# How does zip(*[iter(s)]*n) work in Python?

Tags: python, iterator

```
s = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
n = 3

list(zip(*[iter(s)]*n)) # returns [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
```

How does `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)` work?  What would it look like if it was written with more verbose code?

---

<sub>This is a technique used for [splitting a list into chunks of equal size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443) - see that question for a general overview of the problem.</sub>

Comment: also take a look here where how it works is also explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202461/yield-multiple-objects-at-a-time-from-an-iterable-object/2202485#2202485

Comment: if answers here aren't enough, I blogged it here:  http://telliott99.blogspot.com/2010/01/chunks-of-sequence-in-python.html

Comment: Although very intriguing, this technique must go against the core "readability" value of Python!

Answer (score 130, accepted):

[`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter) is an iterator over a sequence. `[x] * n` produces a list containing `n` quantity of `x`, i.e. a list of length `n`, where each element is `x`. `*arg` unpacks a sequence into arguments for a function call. Therefore you're passing the same iterator 3 times to [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip), and it pulls an item from the iterator each time.

```
x = iter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
print(list(zip(x, x, x)))
```

Comment: **Good to know:** when an iterator `yield`s (= `return`s) an item, you can imagine this item as "consumed". So the next time the iterator is called, it yields the next "unconsumed" item.

Answer (score 53):

The other great answers and comments explain well the roles of [**argument unpacking**](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and [**zip()**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).

As [Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python/2233247#2233247) and [ujukatzel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python/2233289#2233289) say, you pass to `zip()` three references to the same iterator and `zip()` makes 3-tuples of the integers—in order—from each reference to the iterator:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
^                    ^                    ^            
      ^                    ^                    ^
            ^                    ^                    ^
```

And since you ask for a more verbose code sample:

```
chunk_size = 3
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

# iterate over L in steps of 3
for start in range(0,len(L),chunk_size): # xrange() in 2.x; range() in 3.x
    end = start + chunk_size
    print L[start:end] # three-item chunks
```

Following the values of `start` and `end`:

```
[0:3) #[1,2,3]
[3:6) #[4,5,6]
[6:9) #[7,8,9]
```

FWIW, you can get the same result with `map()` with an initial argument of `None`:

```
>>> map(None,*[iter(s)]*3)
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

For more on `zip()` and `map()`:  http://muffinresearch.co.uk/archives/2007/10/16/python-transposing-lists-with-map-and-zip/

Answer (score 35):

I think one thing that's missed in all the answers (probably obvious to those familiar with iterators) but not so obvious to others is -

Since we have the same iterator, it gets consumed and the remaining elements are used by the zip. So if we simply used the list and not the iter 
eg.

```
l = range(9)
zip(*([l]*3)) # note: not an iter here, the lists are not emptied as we iterate 
# output 
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4), (5, 5, 5), (6, 6, 6), (7, 7, 7), (8, 8, 8)]
```

Using iterator, pops the values and only keeps remaining available, so for zip once 0 is consumed 1 is available and then 2 and so on. A very subtle thing, but quite clever!!!

Comment: +1, You saved me! I can't believe that other answers skipped this vital detail assuming everybody knows this. Can you give any reference to a documentation which includes this information?

Answer (score 10):

`iter(s)` returns an iterator for s.

`[iter(s)]*n` makes a list of n times the same iterator for s.

So, when doing `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)`, it extracts an item from all the three iterators from the list in order. Since all the iterators are the same object, it just groups the list in chunks of `n`.

Comment: Not 'n iterators of the same list', but 'n times the same iterator object'. Different iterator objects don't share state, even when they are of the same list.

Comment: Thanks, corrected. Indeed that was what I was "thinking", but wrote something else.

Answer (score 7):

One word of advice for using zip this way. It will truncate your list if it's length is not evenly divisible. To work around this you could either use [itertools.izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) if you can accept fill values. Or you could use something like this:

```
def n_split(iterable, n):
    num_extra = len(iterable) % n
    zipped = zip(*[iter(iterable)] * n)
    return zipped if not num_extra else zipped + [iterable[-num_extra:], ]
```

Usage:

```
for ints in n_split(range(1,12), 3):
    print ', '.join([str(i) for i in ints])
```

Prints:

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
10, 11
```

Comment: This is already documented in `itertools` recipes: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes `grouper` . No need to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 7):

Unwinding layers of "cleverness", you may find this equivalent spelling easier to follow:

```
x = iter(s)
for a, b, c in zip(*([x] * n)):
    print(a, b, c)
```

which is, in turn, equivalent to the even less-clever:

```
x = iter(accounts_iter)
for a, b, c in zip(x, x, x):
    print(a, b, c)
```

Now it should start to become clear. There is only a single iterator object, `x`. On each iteration, `zip()`, under the covers, calls `next(x)` 3 times, once for each iterator object passed to it. But it's the *same* iterator object here each time. So it delivers the first 3 `next(x)` results, and leaves the shared iterator object waiting to deliver its 4th result next. Lather, rinse, repeat.

BTW, I suspect you're parsing `*([iter(x)]*n)` incorrectly in your head. The trailing `*n` happens first, and then the prefix `*` is applied to the n-element list `*n` created. `f(*iterable)` is a shortcut for calling `f()` with a variable number of arguments, one for each object `iterable` delivers.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to break down each partial step to really internalize how it is working. My notes from the REPL:

```
>>> # refresher on using list multiples to repeat item
>>> lst = list(range(15))
>>> lst
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
>>> # lst id value
>>> id(lst)
139755081359872
>>> [id(x) for x in [lst]*3]
[139755081359872, 139755081359872, 139755081359872]

# replacing lst with an iterator of lst
# It's the same iterator three times
>>> [id(x) for x in [iter(lst)]*3 ]
[139755085005296, 139755085005296, 139755085005296]
# without starred expression zip would only see single n-item list.
>>> print([iter(lst)]*3)
[<list_iterator object at 0x7f1b440837c0>, <list_iterator object at 0x7f1b440837c0>, <list_iterator object at 0x7f1b440837c0>]
# Must use starred expression to expand n arguments
>>> print(*[iter(lst)]*3)
<list_iterator object at 0x7f1b4418b1f0> <list_iterator object at 0x7f1b4418b1f0> <list_iterator object at 0x7f1b4418b1f0>

# by repeating the same iterator, n-times,
# each pass of zip will call the same iterator.__next__() n times
# this is equivalent to manually calling __next__() until complete
>>> iter_lst = iter(lst)
>>> ((iter_lst.__next__(), iter_lst.__next__(), iter_lst.__next__()))
(0, 1, 2)
>>> ((iter_lst.__next__(), iter_lst.__next__(), iter_lst.__next__()))
(3, 4, 5)
>>> ((iter_lst.__next__(), iter_lst.__next__(), iter_lst.__next__()))
(6, 7, 8)
>>> ((iter_lst.__next__(), iter_lst.__next__(), iter_lst.__next__()))
(9, 10, 11)
>>> ((iter_lst.__next__(), iter_lst.__next__(), iter_lst.__next__()))
(12, 13, 14)
>>> ((iter_lst.__next__(), iter_lst.__next__(), iter_lst.__next__()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration

# all together now!
# continuing with same iterator multiple times in list
>>> print(*[iter(lst)]*3)
<list_iterator object at 0x7f1b4418b1f0> <list_iterator object at 0x7f1b4418b1f0> <list_iterator object at 0x7f1b4418b1f0>
>>> zip(*[iter(lst)]*3)
<zip object at 0x7f1b43f14e00>
>>> list(zip(*[iter(lst)]*3))
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11), (12, 13, 14)]

# NOTE: must use list multiples. Explicit listing creates 3 unique iterators
>>> [iter(lst)]*3 == [iter(lst), iter(lst), iter(lst)]
False
>>> list(zip(*[[iter(lst), iter(lst), iter(lst)]))
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), ....
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier to see what is happening in python interpreter or `ipython` with `n = 2`:

```
In [35]: [iter("ABCDEFGH")]*2
Out[35]: [<iterator at 0x6be4128>, <iterator at 0x6be4128>]
```

So, we have a list of two iterators which are pointing to the same iterator object. Remember that `iter` on a object returns an iterator object and in this scenario, it is the same iterator twice due to the `*2` python syntactic sugar. Iterators also run only once.

Further, [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) takes any number of iterables ([sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) are [iterables](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)) and creates tuple from i'th element of each of the input sequences. Since both iterators are identical in our case, zip moves the same iterator twice for each 2-element tuple of output.

```
In [41]: help(zip)
Help on built-in function zip in module __builtin__:

zip(...)
    zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]

    Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
    from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated
    in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.
```

The [unpacking (`*`) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2322410/828885) ensures that the iterators run to exhaustion which in this case is until there is not enough input to create a 2-element tuple.

This can be extended to any value of `n` and `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)` works as described.

Comment: Sorry for being slow. But could you explain the "the same iterator twice due to the *2 python syntactic sugar. Iterators also run only once." part please? If so, how come the result is not [("A", "A")....]? Thanks.

Comment: @BowenLiu `*` is just convenience to duplicate an object. Try it with scalars and then with lists. Also try `print(*zip(*[iter("ABCDEFG")]*2))` vs `print(*zip(*[iter("ABCDEFG"), iter("ABCDEFG")]))`. Then start tearing the two down into smaller steps to see what the actually iterator objects in the two statements are.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
zip(*[iter(x)] * 3)
```

is the same as:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
iter_var = iter(x)
zip(iter_var,iter_var,iter_var)
```

Each time `zip()` gets the next value in `iter_var` it moves to the next value of `x`.
Try running `next(iter_var)` to see how this works.