# How can I split a string in Python?

Tags: python, string

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>    [Split python string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character)
>    [What is the most “pythonic” way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

I need to split a string into equal parts. For example, if I have this string:

```
string = "123456781234567812345678"
```

I need to cut every 8 characters:

```
["12345678", "12345678", "12345678"]
```

Comment: I think this has already been asked 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character

Comment: nice find, himanshu! makes me feel good about my own answer, since it's exactly the same. haha.

Comment: @SeanJohnson Hardly, the other answer isn't nearly as enthusiastic!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a great application for a python list comprehension one-liner!

```
my_str="123456781234567812345678"
splits=[my_str[x:x+8] for x in range(0,len(my_str),8)]
//splits = ["12345678","12345678","12345678"]
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I'd rename `str`. It's conflicting with the built-in type `str`.

Comment: That second answer from the linked question is pretty neat: `map(''.join, zip(*[iter(my_str)] * 8))`.

Comment: It seems like entire civilizations could conceivably fit into clever Python one-liners. I'm always amazed.

Answer (score -6):

This might help:

> ```
> str.split(str="", num=string.count(str)).
> ```
>
> str: any delimeter, by default it is space.
>
> num: number of lines to be made.

You can get more info [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about splitting into strings of a given length rather than by a delimiter

Comment: It's nice that you did a search to help the question author, but simply copying the first result you find without any explanation (even with citation) really isn't helping. The OP might just use `8` for the delimiter and think it works.