# Sublime Os X output window word-wrap

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I am coding Python using Sublime 2 in OS X, but whenever I run cmd+B the output is long and not word wrapped. I enabled word-wrap but I think it's only for editor itself. Any solution is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cmd-B` is just a convenience wrapper around a terminal execution. There are two ways to prevent the line from overflowing:

1) If your output is a string, which I think it is, you can use something like the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328108/how-can-i-split-a-string-in-python). Example:

```
char_size = 80
pieces = [my_long_str[x:x+char_size] for x in range(0,len(my_long_str),char_size)]

for piece in pieces:
    print piece
```

This will print every 80 characters worth of content on a new line.

2) If you're output is a list, you can use the `pprint` module to pretty-print your list by listing each element on different lines. Check out the `pprint.pprint` module in particular [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint).

Comment: yes it works, thanks. but Sublime has a pretty bad output IMO

Comment: Is there a way toooo tell just to the wordwrap on python files?