# How to use Python's groupby

Tags: python, string, python-itertools

How can I split a string on 2's, eg "string" would be split into groups of "st", "ri","ng".
I check the doc, groupby from itertools seems to be what i need. However, is there a way to do it simply by not using itertools?
thanks

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks?lq=1

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks/434328#434328) for a non-itertools version.

Comment: This is the actual answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328108/how-can-i-split-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it without itertools, but it will be slower.  Unless it's a learning excersize, use the "grouper" recipe from the [itertools page:](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Comment: Note that `izip_longest` requires Python 2.6+

Comment: I prefer [@nosklo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/434328/790387) from the linked question since it doesn't have version restrictions

Comment: Depending on Python 2.6, released in 2008, is hardly a serious version restriction.

Comment: thanks. i guess if I compile my script to executable, it might not have version restrictions?

Comment: @dorothy if you use `py2exe` or `freeze`, the version you're using is bundled with the program, so you don't have to worry about versions.

Answer (score 1):

```
s='your input string'
ans=[  ]
i=0
while i < len(s):
    ans.append( s[ i:i+2 ] )
    i+=2
print ans
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do the two character groups without itertools, you can use this:

```
s = 'string'
groups = [''.join(g) for g in zip(s[:-1:2], s[1::2])]
```

Note that this only works properly for even-length strings.