# Testing the equality of the sum of a digits within a number on python?

Tags: python, equality

for example `def f(n):`

and I wanna check whether the sum of the numbers within `n` equal to 100 whether it is in 1s, 2s, 3,s 4s, 5s and so on, depending on the length of `n`.

```
f(5050)
>>> True
```

This tests whether `5 + 0 + 5 + 0 == 100` and whether `50 + 50 ==100` and if any are true, it returns `True`.

Whether it tests in 1s, 2s 3s 4s and so on, depends on the length of the number. For example a number with a length of 5 can only be tested in 1s.

```
f(12345)
>>> False
```

This tests whether `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 == 100` and only that.

If the length of `n` was 15, it would test the digits in 1s, 3s and 5s.

and finally one more example:

```
f(25252525)
>>> True
```

This would test whether `2+5+2+5+2+5+2+5 == 100` and `25+25+25+25==100` and whether `2525+2525==100`
So `n`, which has a length of 8 would be tested in 1s , 2s , and 4s. It cannot be tested with 3s and 5s because the length of all the digits within the number being summed up must be the same.

I hope I was able to explain what I'm after. Usually I would post what I've tried but I have no idea how to iterate over the digits of a number in such a way

Comment: hint: `x = str(my_number)`, and now you can inspect the individual digits of `my_number` by indexing `x`.

Comment: But I thought indexing wouldn't work because n can be any number with any length

Comment: so what is `f(343)`? Or is your function only supposed to handle positive integers with an even number of digits?

Comment: Strings can be any length too. I don't see a problem there.

Comment: it would be False. 3 + 4 + 3 = 10 and not 100

Comment: Then `f(34343)`? :) My question is how to "split" numbers with odd number of digits.

Comment: The part with "whether 5 + 0 + 5 + 0 == 100 and whether 50 + 50 ==100 and if any are true" changes this from a tidy problem into a messy problem, by the way. Are you sure it has to look for all combinations?

Comment: in any way that the the numbers being summed up are all the same length. That would be 3 + 4 + 3 + 4 + 3. Look at my example of a number with a length of 15

Comment: so `f(100)` returns True? Just clarifying some stuff

Comment: @Shashank , something like f(999999999991) would also be true when tested with 1s. This is why different combinations are required

Comment: Is this for use in something, or simply a programming exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this does the trick. Not sure though:

```
def f(n):
    s = str(n)
    l = len(s)
    for n in (n for n in range(1, l + 1) if l % n == 0):
        ints = [int(''.join(x)) for x in zip(*[iter(s)]*n)]
        if sum(ints) == 100:
            return True
    return False
```

The `zip` thing comes from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip). It's a little weird but it allows me to split the string up into n-length segments and then join it back together so I can apply an `int` mapping and then a `sum` reduction.

The generator just gets all positive divisors of `l` from `1` to `l`, both inclusive. There may be faster ways of doing it for large `n` using `math.sqrt` and `divmod`.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome reply. This code seems to be working really well. Just one more thing, is there a way to have the digits, which are being added separately, squared separately? For example it checks for f(5050) checks for 50^2 + 50^2 instead of 50+50

Comment: @Roger Sure. Just do `map(lambda x: x**2, ints)` to get a a list (or iterable in Python 3) of all the squared values. Then cast `sum()` on that expression. :) Alternatively you can do `[x**2 for x in ints]` That's a list comprehension and basically it does the same thing as `map` (except its a bit faster and easier to read).

Answer (score 2):

The below approach uses generator to split the integer, and no `integer <-> string` conversion.

This will likely be the most efficient approach of the ones currently listed.

```
import math

# Define a generator that will split the integer v into chunks of length cl
# Note: This will return the chunks in "reversed" order.
#   split(1234, 2) => [34, 12]
def split(v, cl):
    while v:
        (v,c) = divmod(v, 10**cl)
        yield c


def f(v):
    # Determine the number of digits in v
    n = int(math.log10(v)) + 1
    m = int(math.sqrt(v))
    # Check all chunk lengths in [1, sqrt(v)]
    for cl in range(m):
        # Skip the chunk lengths that would result in unequal chunk sizes 
        if n % (cl+1): continue
        # Create a generator, to split the value v into chunks of length cl
        chunks = split(v, cl+1)
        # If the sum of the chunks is 100, print a message and return True
        if sum(chunks) == 100:
            print("sum = 100 with chunklength: %d" % cl)
            return True
    # If we get here, none of the chunk lengths result in a sum of 100, return False
    return False

print(f(5050))      # True (cl=2)
print("---")
print(f(12345))     # False
print("---")
print(f(25252525))  # True (cl=2)
print("---")
```

Output:

```
sum = 100 with chunklength: 2
True
---
False
---
sum = 100 with chunklength: 2
True
---
```

Without comments and debugging `print`:

```
import math

def split(v, cl):
    while v:
        (v,c) = divmod(v, 10**cl)
        yield c

def f(v):
    n = int(math.log10(v)) + 1
    m = int(math.sqrt(v))
    for cl in range(m):
        if n % (cl+1): continue
        if sum(split(v, cl+1)) == 100: return True
    return False

print(f(5050))      # True
print(f(12345))     # False
print(f(25252525))  # True
```

Comment: Your names should really be longer and more descriptive, and I disagree with onelining those `if` statements and checking against `100` within `f()` (seems like something that should go outside)… That said, your answer is the simplest currently on here and requires only the standard `math` module. Nice job. +1

Comment: @BlacklightShining I understand that it may be confusing, but the variables names weren't really arbitrary letters as they may seem.  `f()` was taken from the OP's code, `v` is the **v**alue, `c` is the **c**hunk, `cl` is the **c**hunk **l**ength, `n` is the **n**umber of digits, `m` is the **m**ax value of the for loop.  As for in-lining, I have mixed feelings about it in general.  My reaction to them fall somewhere on a "this makes perfect sense" to "this is crazy" spectrum.  In the case of simple blocks (`continue`, `return True`), it usually falls in the "this isn't unreasonable" range.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the numbers are always positive integers, you can just `divmod()` them by `10` until you get to zero:

```
def int_iter(number):
    while number > 0:
        number, last_digit = divmod(number, 10)
        yield last_digit
```

Note that gives you the digits in reverse order. That doesn't matter if you're just adding them together, though.

You can pass this around or use it in a `for` loop, like any other iterable:

```
digit_sum = sum(int_iter(number))
```

If you really need a sequence, just pass it to `list()`:

```
digit_list = list(int_iter(number))
```

And if you need them in most-significant-first order, pass it to `reversed()`:

```
digits_msf = reversed(list(int_iter(number)))
```

---

**EDIT:**

Whoops, I missed…about half of the question. Things are rather more complicated. You'll need a function to get all the factors of a number—I'm sure there are plenty, so I'll leave that as an excercise for you. Let's assume there's a function `factors(number)` that returns an iterable of all a number's factors (including nonprimes and 1, but not `number` itself). We'll also use the `int_iter()` from my original answer, an `int_from_digits()` that takes a list of digits and returns a single integer (sort of like the inverse of `int_iter()`), and something called `grouper()` from [the `itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def int_from_digits(digits):
    "Generate an integer from an iterable of single decimal digits"
    # int_from_digits([4, 0, 2, 8, 9]) --> 40289
    # int_from_digits([]) --> 0
    number = 0
    for digit in digits:
        number *= 10
        number += digit
    return number

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def digit_subsequences(number):
    digits = list(reversed(list(int_iter(number))))
    for factor in factors(number):
        for digit_grouping in grouper(digits, factor):
            yield int_from_digits(digit_grouping)
```

Finally, armed with all these tools (or rather, one tool and its dependencies), we can perform your check with a simple comprehension and a call to `any()`:

```
any(digit_subsequence == 100 for digit_subsequence in digit_subsequences(number))
```

Comment: How does this help find whether the sum of any consecutive combinations of equal-length digits is equal to 100?

Comment: Yeah, I started to answer this question, but then I noticed the part about combinations...

Answer (score 1):

One possible way, separated into functions for each logical step :

1. [Get factors of `n`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800193/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-finding-all-the-factors-of-a-number-in-python) :

---

```
def get_factors(n):    
    return set(reduce(list.__add__, 
                ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0)))
```

2. For each `l` factor of `n`, [split `str(n)` into chunks of length `l`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673060/split-string-into-strings-by-length) :

---

```
def get_chunks(str_n, chunk_size):
    total_size = len(str_n)
    return [int(str_n[i:i+chunk_size]) for i in range(0, total_size, chunk_size)]
```

3. Check if sum of chunks in step 2 equals 100.

---

```
def f(n):
    factors = get_factors(n)
    for l in factors:
        if sum(get_chunks(str(n), l)) == 100:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def factors(num):
    yield 1
    for i in range(2, num - 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            yield i


def pieces(string, sz):
    for i in range(0, len(string), sz):
        yield string[i:i+sz]


def check_sum(string):
    for f in factors(len(string)):
        pcs = pieces(string, f)
        if sum([int(x) for x in pcs]) == 100:
            print 'True'
            return
    print 'False'

>>> check_sum('5050')
True
>>> check_sum('25252525')
True
>>> check_sum('12345')
False
```