# How to remove spaces from string and slice the string into multiple chunks of fixed length

Tags: python

I have a string which needs to be processed:

1. Remove all spaces
2. Group the resulting string in a characters of 5

Currently I have:

```
new = ''
sym = " !#$%^&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{}~"""
gap = []
for char in text:
    if char in sym or char in gap:
        sym += char
result = []
```

Anyone knows how?

Comment: Can you format the code?

Comment: What do you mean by **blocks of 5 kind**?

Comment: So like the result is like this SAMPLE SAMPLE SAMPLE

Comment: Each letter or number in the string need to saved in word lengths of 5

Comment: Give an example input and output, it's hard to guess what it's supposed to do based on non-working code.

Comment: input: this is a sample text
out put: thisi sasmp letex t

Comment: So which part are you having trouble with, removing spaces or dividing to groups of 5? And how is the code you posted at all relevant to the question, as it doesn't even attempt to perform either task?

Comment: i need help with both

Answer (score 2):

You worded your question really confusingly, but if you want to remove all white spaces from a string, you can use replace:

```
name = "Foo Bar"
name = name.replace(" ","")

print(name) 
# Output: "FooBar"
```

Comment: but the it needs to be re arranged so the each letter from the string that has the spaces removed are saved in word lengths of 5

Comment: Once you have removed the spaces from the string, you can split it by lengths of 5 by using the solution posted by this user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673060/split-string-into-strings-by-length

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your string is sym and

1. You want to remove all spaces from `sym`
2. Make a block (list) of    words (strings) of length 5.

Python code in steps:

```
In [1]: sym = " !#$%^&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{}~" #This is your input string

In [2]: sym = sym.replace(" ","") #remove all "" (spaces)

In [3]: sym #Lets check the output
Out[3]: "!#$%^&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{}~"

In [4]: sym_list = [ sym[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(sym), 5)] # use range to generate iteration with increment 5 each time

In [5]: sym_list #So, did we get blocks of 5 chars? hope so. 
Out[5]: 
['!#$%^',
 "&'()*",
 '+,-./',
 '01234',
 '56789',
 ':;<=>',
 '?@ABC',
 'DEFGH',
 'IJKLM',
 'NOPQR',
 'STUVW',
 'XYZ[\\',
 ']^_`a',
 'bcdef',
 'ghijk',
 'lmnop',
 'qrstu',
 'vwxyz',
 '{}~']
```

Correct me if any of my assumptions are incorrect.