# I need to be able to wrap a string every 30 characters. Python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x, data-manipulation

i am using python 3. I need to be able to wrap a string every 30 characters. ([30 characters] \n [rest of characters]. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: google "python wrap string" (before you ask)

Answer (score 0):

assuming input contains your string you could do it like this:

```
wrap = 30
myList = [input[i:i+wrap] for i in range(0, len(input), wrap)]
print myList
```

@jonatan is right btw, a quick google search would have brought you, among other answers to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46591040/4814367) from a similar question a view years ago.

Comment: Thanks, a lot! Could you please talk me through what the code does, it almost works exactly as I need but there is ['input'] around the output.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean with "there is ['input'] around the output." but the above code splits your input in a list where each element is 30 characters long. I edited my answer to make it more clear.