# How to split input by length in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables, type-conversion

I'm creating a encryption program in Python where user will input like <<< This is the text which is decrypted!
How can I show the result as output?
Is there any way to split "This is the text which is decrypted!"  into  different variables value by length? Like:

```
input_list=input.split(len(8))
for i in input_list:
    input+n=i. #string
    n +=1
```

And it will turn:

```
input1="This is " 
input2=" the text" 
input3=" which is" 
input4=" decrypted"
input5="!"
print (input1+input2+input3+....)
```

And the output will show the the same text as inputted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string into strings by length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673060/split-string-into-strings-by-length)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can come up with is by using a list or dictionary, for example(with a list):

```
input = "This is the text which is decrypted!"
output = []
length = 8
for i in range(len(input))[::length]:
    output.append(input[i:i+length])
print(output[0])
print(output[1])
#...
```

Comment: Could be written simpler as `range(0, len(input), length)`. And then even transformed to a list comprehension: `output = [input[i:i+length] for i in range(0, len(input), length)]`. *But*, it's important to point out that `input` shouldn't be used as a variable as it is a built-in name.

Comment: Yep, I apologize for the bad variable naming =.=