# split a string into two dimentional array python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I want to do is to take a string(cipher) and devide it to several groups and **not to copy** them (assume that every 7 characters to one group), All I want to do is take every 7 letters and add them to one row in two dimentional array and the same for the next 7 and so on.

I have tried to do that with two dimentional array and I have some problem that its always change all my arrays for every update, and I dont want to copy it.

Let me give you an example:

```
def splitter(cipher,key_length):

    rows = math.ceil(len(cipher)/key_length)
    columns = key_length
    arr = [[""]*columns]*rows
    arr1=[]
    for row in range(rows):
        for column in range(columns):
            if (row * columns + column)< len(cipher):
                arr[row][column] = cipher[row * columns + column]
            else:
                arr[row][column] = ""
        arr1.append(arr[row])
    print(arr1)


splitter("QPWKALVRXCQZIKGRBPFAEOMFLJMSDZVDHXCXJYEBIMTRQWNMEAIZRVKCVKVLXNEICFZPZCZZHKMLVZVZIZRRQWDKECHOSNYXXLSPMYKVQXJTDCIOMEEXDQVSRXLRLKZHOV",7)
```

the result of the print is that its duplicated the least 7 characters for the all array, and I coudnt figure out why this happening, what I'm missing?

the result of this print is:

```
[['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', ''], ['Z', 'H', 'O', 'V', '', '', '']]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: And what you want to do is covered here: [how do you split a list into evenly sized chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Comment: Yes this is thie one List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```py
arr = [[""] * columns] * rows
```

This is a Python "gotcha" - a piece of code which looks on the surface like it should do one thing, but actually does a quite different thing, though the difference is subtle.

What you wanted was a list containing `rows` different rows. What you actually get is a list containing that many references to **the same row**. The code `[""] * columns` only creates one list, so when you fill in the second row's values into that list, it overwrites the first row's values which were previously stored there; then the third row's values overwrite the second row's values, and so on, because they are all references to the same list.

You may find it helpful to [visualise the execution step-by-step](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20math%0A%0Adef%20splitter%28cipher,key_length%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20rows%20%3D%20math.ceil%28len%28cipher%29/key_length%29%0A%20%20%20%20columns%20%3D%20key_length%0A%20%20%20%20arr%20%3D%20%5B%5B%22%22%5D*columns%5D*rows%0A%20%20%20%20arr1%3D%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20row%20in%20range%28rows%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20column%20in%20range%28columns%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28row%20*%20columns%20%2B%20column%29%3C%20len%28cipher%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20arr%5Brow%5D%5Bcolumn%5D%20%3D%20cipher%5Brow%20*%20columns%20%2B%20column%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20arr%5Brow%5D%5Bcolumn%5D%20%3D%20%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20arr1.append%28arr%5Brow%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20print%28arr1%29%0A%0A%0Asplitter%28%22ABCDEFGHI%22,3%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=44&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false), to understand what's going on. This link uses the rather excellent [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/) tool.

---

The solution is to create `rows` different lists explicitly:

```py
arr = [[""] * columns for i in range(rows)]
```

Comment: might be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673060/split-string-into-strings-by-length