# Python: Split number in two parts

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python and i would like to split a string of numbers like "12" or "1234" in two parts by separating the string in the middle with " ". e.g.: "12" --> "1 2", "1234" --> "12 34"

How can i do this? I've tried it multiple times with split() now and I just don't make it

Pseudocode:

`split("12")`

`result = "1 2"`

Comment: Have you tried slicing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string into strings by length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673060/split-string-into-strings-by-length)

Comment: This is what you have expected https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-split-given-string-into-equal-halves/

Answer (score 1):

one way to do that

```
a = '1234'
splitter = len(a)//2
print(a[:splitter], a[splitter:])
```