# spliting values in a dictionary into fragments and making new values

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict={a:qwertyuiop} dict1={a:qw,b:er,c:ty,d:ui,e:op}
```

I want to create dict 1 from dict with splitting the value with length of 2

I have tried

```
value1=dict.value()
value2=value1.split(2)
```

It does not accept integer and I obviously using the wrong function, I have searched on the net but could not find it, which function should I use?

Comment: (partial) duplicate [Split string into strings by length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673060/split-string-into-strings-by-length)

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I have tried split function but it only accepts string parameters.

Comment: What's "this value"?

Comment: What result do you expect ? can you show the code that you've tried and its result ?

Comment: Please checkout the [article on how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have edited the question sorry for the last mess I hope it is ok now

Comment: You do realize the keys in a dictionary must be unique and cannot repeat, right?

Comment: I have edited again

Answer (score 0):

```
# Defining variables
d = {'a': 'abcde', 'b': 'cdefghi'}
n = 2

# One-Liner:
d1 = dict([(i + j*len(d), word) for j, key in enumerate(d.keys()) for i, word in enumerate([d[key][i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(d[key]), n)])])
print(d1)

# Normal code
d2 = dict()
for j, key in enumerate(d.keys()):  # Enumerating threw the keys
    for i, word in enumerate([d[key][i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(d[key]), n)]):  # Enumerating threw n-characters at a time
        d2[i + j*len(d)] = word  # Assigning to the right key with math
print(d2)
```

One downside to this code is that we are losing the keys,
This has to be done in order to keep having only one key per value.

Output for d1: `{0: 'ab', 1: 'cd', 2: 'cd', 3: 'ef', 4: 'gh', 5: 'i'}`

Output for d2: `{0: 'ab', 1: 'cd', 2: 'cd', 3: 'ef', 4: 'gh', 5: 'i'}`

Answer (score 0):

This function allows you to do exactly that, and gives you the choice of integer keys or letter keys by typing `int` or `chr` as the third function argument:

```py
def ds(d,n,v=chr):
  return({v(int(y/n)+[96 if v==chr else 0][0]):"".join([str(d[z]) for z in d])[y-n:y] for y in range(n,len("".join([d[z] for z in d]))+n,n)})
```

This works by first iterating through the dictionary values and returning the value of each key (in the `str(d[z]) for z in d`). The function then joins the list of string values together, (the "".join part), and then parses through the length that string (the `for y in range(...)` part) and returns a dictionary with values split every `n`th time.

Examples:

```py
a=ds(myDictionary,2) #split every second character (string keys)
print(a)
#{'a': 'qw', 'b': 'er', 'c': 'ty', 'd': 'ui', 'e': 'op'}

b=ds(myDictionary,3,int) #split every third (integer keys)
print(b)
#{1: 'qwe', 2: 'rty', 3: 'uio', 4: 'p'}

c=ds(myDictionary,56,char) #split every fifty-sixth (string keys)
print(c)
#{'a': 'qwertyuiop'}
```

Also, no outside modules required! This is all built-in stuff.