# Splitting characters in string

Tags: python

I have a string such as `'01301347'` and I want to split it into something like `'01-13-30-01-13-34-47'`.

Is it possible to do something like this using `split()`?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character?rq=1

Comment: Split should be used for finding letters or numbers, and it is an inefficient process so try not to use it when you can do something else.

Answer (score 3):

You want to splice and join, not split:

```
'-'.join(mystr[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0, len(mystr)-1))
```

You could also use `itertools.islice` and `itertools.izip`:

```
'-'.join((a+b for a,b in itertools.izip(mystr, itertools.islice(mystr, 1, len(mystr)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = '01301347'
>>> '-'.join(s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s) - 1))
'01-13-30-01-13-34-47'
```

or you can use:

```
>>> '-'.join(a+b for a,b in zip(s, s[1:]))
'01-13-30-01-13-34-47'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> '-'.join(starmap(add,zip(*[iter(s)]*2)))
'01-30-13-47'
```

#### Explanation:

```
>>> zip(*[iter(s)]*2)
[('0', '1'), ('3', '0'), ('1', '3'), ('4', '7')]
```

[`add`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.add) is equivalent for `+`: `a + b = add(a,b)`

[`starmap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) applies function to unpacked list of arguments from each value from iterable.

```
>>> list(starmap(add,zip(*[iter(s)]*2)))
['01', '30', '13', '47']
```

Lastly we just `join` them:

```
>>> '-'.join(starmap(add,zip(*[iter(s)]*2)))
'01-30-13-47'
```

---

By the way, we can avoid having to use `starmap` and `add` by writing it in a bit different way:

```
>>> '-'.join(map(''.join,zip(*[iter(s)]*2)))
'01-30-13-47'
```