# Split a string to even sized chunks

Tags: python, string, tuples

How would I be able to take a string like `'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'`
and split it into 4 length tuples like (`aaaa`,`aaaa`,`aaaa`)

Comment: for x in s:x = s[0:4];s = s[4:];print(x)

Comment: related: [What is the most “pythonic” way to iterate over a list in chunks?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/434287/4279)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use [`textwrap.wrap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap):

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> s = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
>>> textwrap.wrap(s, 4)
['aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaa']
```

Comment: Won't this fail if the string contains spaces?

Comment: `textwrap` is very powerful and IMO, for a precise task like this, offers far too many options for things like replacing tabs with spaces, fixing sentence punctuation, etc. I would be more comfortable using something much simpler.

Answer (score 25):

Using list comprehension, generator expression:

```
>>> s = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
>>> [s[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(s), 4)]
['aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaa']

>>> tuple(s[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(s), 4))
('aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaa')

>>> s = 'a bcdefghi j'
>>> tuple(s[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(s), 4))
('a bc', 'defg', 'hi j')
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution using regex:

```
>>> s = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('[a-z]{4}', s)
['aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa']
>>>
```

Comment: A regular expression is a bit overkill for this.

Comment: The owner was asking for a solution, not asking for the most optimize one, so i just put as we can solve in that way too. never mind, i know its not the best of its kind.

Comment: Actually, that's a really nice solution (apart from regular expressions being slower when used in bulk) and easier to understand on first sight than the `zip()` solution. And it can easily be changed to work with arbitrary characters, including newlines: `re.findall('.{4}', s, re.DOTALL)` - Or even accept incomplete tails: `re.findall('.{1,4}', s, re.DOTALL)`

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), `zip(*[iter(s)]*4)`:

```
In [113]: s = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'

In [114]: [''.join(item) for item in zip(*[iter(s)]*4)]
Out[114]: ['aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa']
```

Note that `textwrap.wrap` may not split `s` into strings of length 4 if the string contains spaces:

```
In [43]: textwrap.wrap('I am a hat', 4)
Out[43]: ['I am', 'a', 'hat']
```

The grouper recipe is faster than using `textwrap`:

```
In [115]: import textwrap

In [116]: %timeit [''.join(item) for item in zip(*[iter(s)]*4)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.41 µs per loop

In [117]: %timeit textwrap.wrap(s, 4)
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.5 µs per loop
```

And the grouper recipe can work with *any iterator*, while `textwrap` only works with strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'abcdefghi'
```

k - no of parts of string

```
k = 3
```

parts - list to store parts of string

```
parts = [s[i:i+k] for i in range(0, len(s), k)]
```

---

*parts --> ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']*

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'abcdef'
```

We need to split in parts of 2

```
[s[pos:pos+2] for pos,i in enumerate(list(s)) if pos%2 == 0]
```

Answer:

```
['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this method is simpler. But the message length must be split with split_size. Or letters must be added to the message. Example: message = "lorem ipsum_" then the added letter can be deleted.

```
message = "lorem ipsum"

array = []

temp = ""

split_size = 3

for i in range(1, len(message) + 1):
    temp += message[i - 1]

    if i % split_size == 0:
        array.append(temp)
        temp = ""

print(array)
```

Output:
['lor', 'em ', 'ips']

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible solution to the given problem:

```
def split_by_length(text, width):
    width = max(1, width)
    chunk = ""
    for v in text:
        chunk += v
        if len(chunk) == width:
            yield chunk
            chunk = ""

    if chunk:
        yield chunk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = "123456789"
    for i in range(20):
        print(i, list(split_by_length(x, i)))
```

Output:

```
0 ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
1 ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
2 ['12', '34', '56', '78', '9']
3 ['123', '456', '789']
4 ['1234', '5678', '9']
5 ['12345', '6789']
6 ['123456', '789']
7 ['1234567', '89']
8 ['12345678', '9']
9 ['123456789']
10 ['123456789']
11 ['123456789']
12 ['123456789']
13 ['123456789']
14 ['123456789']
15 ['123456789']
16 ['123456789']
17 ['123456789']
18 ['123456789']
19 ['123456789']
```

Answer (score 0):

The kiddy way

```
def wrap(string, max_width):
    i=0
    strings = []
    s = ""
    for x in string:
        i+=1
        if i == max_width:
            s = s + x
            strings.append(s)
            s = ""
            i = 0
        else:
            s = s + x
    strings.append(s)
    return strings

wrap('ABCDEFGHIJKLIMNOQRSTUVWXYZ',4)
# output: ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL', 'IMNO', 'QRST', 'UVWX', 'YZ']
```

Answer (score 0):

This function uses recursion.

```
s = 'dasffvvcsadcadscsdsdcsadssdfsdfsdfdfs'

delimiter = 5

def reccursive_split(data, delimiter, current_list = []):
    if len(data) > delimiter:
        current_list.append(data[:delimiter])
        return reccursive_split(data[delimiter:], delimiter, current_list)
    else:
        current_list.append(data)
        return current_list

print(reccursive_split(s, delimiter))
```