# format string to be more human readable

Tags: python

I'm looking for a more elegant way to format a string into a human readable syntax.

```
>>> a = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX'
>>> # magic
>>> print(a)
'ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP-QRST-UVWX'
```

What I got so far:

```
>>> a = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX'
>>> b = map(''.join, zip(*[iter(a)]*4))
>>> print(b)
['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL', 'MNOP', 'QRST', 'UVWX']
>>> c = '-'.join(b)
>>> print(c)
'ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP-QRST-UVWX'
```

Comment: For what its worth, I think what you have there is rather good.  But if you're looking for alternatives supplying some concrete criteria (speed, memory usage, etc) would be helpful

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - concatenated string to a tuple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351275/python-concatenated-string-to-a-tuple)

Comment: To be honest - no speed or memory criteria at all. I just thought "hmmm, it wouldn't be the first time to see some 'better' solution at stackoverflow"

Comment: @init3, well the solution in the possible duplicate is gorgeous, so you should check that out (even though you've already accepted an answer here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in one line with this:

```
>>> a = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX'
>>> "-".join([a[i:i+4] for i in range(len(a)/4)])
 'ABCD-BCDE-CDEF-DEFG-EFGH-FGHI'
```

In python 3 use: `"-".join([a[i:i+4] for i in range(int(len(a)/4))])`

Comment: You can use `//` to perform integer division in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

def make_elegant(s, groupsize=4, joiner='-', pad=''):
    return joiner.join(''.join(block) for block in grouper(s, groupsize, pad))

print make_elegant('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX')
```

returns

```
ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP-QRST-UVWX
```