# Dividing text into parts

Tags: python

I need to split the text into 3 parts, now I have this:

```
response = "some text"
res = len(response)
part_1 = response[0:res//2]
part_2 = response[res//2:]
print(part_1)
print(part_2)
```

this code divides the text into 2 parts, but how can I make it divide into 3 parts?

Comment: you need to define "three parts", if its divided by 3, then in case like length 8, should you have 2, 3, 3 or 3, 2, 3 or 3, 3, 2?

Comment: whatever you like, I just need to split the text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string to even sized chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351275/split-a-string-to-even-sized-chunks)

Comment: partially, but I need to split the text exactly through the function in such a way as I have already done

Comment: If you understand what this code does, what troubles you when you attempt to modify it to make 3 parts instead?

Comment: `part = res//3` and `response[ 0*part : 1*part ]`  `response[ 1*part : 2*part ]`  `response[ 2*part : 3*part ]` or safer `response[ 2*part : ]`

Answer (score -1):

I would do it with a recursive method. Try this:

```python
def split_str(seq, chunk, skip_tail=False):
    lst = []
    if chunk <= len(seq):
        lst.extend([seq[:chunk]])
        lst.extend(split_str(seq[chunk:], chunk, skip_tail))
    elif not skip_tail and seq:
        lst.extend([seq])
    return lst
```

The answer is returned as a list. If we did:

```py
print(split_str("some text", 3))
```

We would get a list looking like: `['som', 'e t', 'ext']`

If you don't want to include spaces, add `.replace(" ", ""), like this:

```py
print(split_str("some text".replace(" ", ""), 3))
```

This gives us: `['som', 'ete', 'xt']`