# Split a string after multiple delimiters and include it

Tags: python, regex, string, split

Hello I'm trying to split a string without removing the delimiter and it can have multiple delimiters.

The delimiters can be 'D', 'M' or 'Y'
For example:

```
>>>string = '1D5Y4D2M'
>>>re.split(someregex, string) #should ideally return
['1D', '5Y', '4D', '2M']
```

To keep the delimiter I use [Python split() without removing the delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866128/python-split-without-removing-the-delimiter)

```
>>> re.split('([^D]+D)', '1D5Y4D2M')
['', '1D', '', '5Y4D', '2M']
```

For multiple delimiters I use [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)

```
>>> re.split('(D|M|Y)', '1D5Y4D2M')
['1', 'D', '5', 'Y', '4', 'D', '2', 'M', '']
```

Combining both doesn't quite make it.

```
>>> re.split('([^D]+D|[^M]+M|[^Y]+Y)', string)
['', '1D', '', '5Y4D', '', '2M', '']
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How about [`(?<!\d)\B(?=\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/thcSl8/1)

Comment: See [Split a string to even sized chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351275/split-a-string-to-even-sized-chunks). Or `re.findall(r'\d+[YMD]', text)`

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `findall()` in your case. How about:

```
re.findall(r'\d+[DYM]', string
```

Which will result in:

```
['1D', '5Y', '4D', '2M']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=(?:D|Y|M))
```

You need 0 width assertion split.Can be done using `regex` module python.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/aKV13g/1

Comment: works great can you detail the use of : and of the ?s ?

Comment: @davidserero its just for non capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

You can split at the locations right after `D`, `Y` or `M` but not at the end of the string with

```py
re.split(r'(?<=[DYM])(?!$)', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JzEYhg/1). Details:

- `(?<=[DYM])` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `D` or `Y` or `M`
- `(?!$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the current position is the string end position.

**Note**

In the current scenario, `(?<=[DYM])` can be used instead of a more verbose `(?<=D|Y|M)` since all alternatives are single characters. If you have multichar delimiters, you would have to use a non-capturing group, `(?:...)`, with lookbehind alternatives inside it. For example, to separate right after `Y`, `DX` and `MZB` you would use `(?:(?<=Y)|(?<=DX)|(?<=MZB))`. See [Python Regex Engine - "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20089922/3832970)

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work fine without regex or split
time complexity O(n)

```
string = '1D5Y4D2M'
temp=''
res = []
for x in string:
    if x=='D':
        temp+='D'
        res.append(temp)
        temp=''
    elif x=='M':
        temp+='M'
        res.append(temp)
        temp=''
    elif x=='Y':
        temp+='Y'
        res.append(temp)
        temp=''
    else:
        temp+=x
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

using translate

```
string = '1D5Y4D2M'

delimiters = ['D', 'Y', 'M']
result = string.translate({ord(c): f'{c}*' for c in delimiters}).strip('.*').split('*')
print(result)

>>> ['1D', '5Y', '4D', '2M']
```