# How do I format an MD5 hash with dashes between pairs of digits in python?

Tags: python, asp.net-membership, md5

How do I format an MD5 hash with dashes between pairs of digits in python?

For example, I can generate a hex string like this:

```
from hashlib import md5
print md5("Testing123!").hexdigest()
```

Which gives this output:

```
b8f58c3067916bbfb50766aa8bddd42c
```

How can I format the output like this:

```
B8-F5-8C-30-67-91-6B-BF-B5-07-66-AA-8B-DD-D4-2C
```

(Note: This is to match the format used by the ASP.NET Membership Provider to store password hashes in the database, so I can interface with it from Python.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A really fun way would be to do this:

```
>>> x = 'b8f58c3067916bbfb50766aa8bddd42c' # your md5
>>> '-'.join(a + b for a, b in zip(x[0::2], x[1::2])).upper()
'B8-F5-8C-30-67-91-6B-BF-B5-07-66-AA-8B-DD-D4-2C'
```

Comment: And just use [``str.upper``](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) to make it uppercase.

Comment: I love this approach!

Comment: While this is nice and short, I find it difficult to read. Too much happening on a single line for my taste.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
>>> def two_chars(s):
...    while s:
...       head = s[:2]
...       s = s[2:]
...       yield head.upper()
...
>>> print "-".join(two_chars(s))
B8-F5-8C-30-67-91-6B-BF-B5-07-66-AA-8B-DD-D4-2C
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer in [Split python string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character) you could do something like

```
hash = md5("Testing123!").hexdigest()
hash = "-".join([hash[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(hash),2)])
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
from hashlib import md5

password = "Testing123!"

def passwordEncoder(password):
    """Return encoded password."""
    return list(md5(password).hexdigest())

def is_even(num):
    """Return whether the number num is even, skip first."""
    if not num == 0:
        return num % 2 == 0

def passwordFormatter(password):
    index = 0
    final_list = []
    while index < len(new_pass):
        letter = new_pass[index]
        if is_even(index):
            final_list.append("-")
        final_list.append(letter.upper())

        index += 1

    return "".join(final_list)

new_pass = passwordEncoder(password)
print passwordFormatter(new_pass)
```

Produces the output:

```
python string.py 
B8-F5-8C-30-67-91-6B-BF-B5-07-66-AA-8B-DD-D4-2C
```

Comment: did you actually read the question and other answers before you?

Comment: Answered at same time. This produces proper output the OP requested so not sure why the -1? As seen in the above responses, they have a shorter code snippet which is helpful.
python string.py 
B8-F5-8C-30-67-91-6B-BF-B5-07-66-AA-8B-DD-D4-2C

Comment: -1 because I believe that for what the OP asked you are doing way too much and as you've seen with other answers the same result can be achieved much easier..