# Dividing a string into a list of smaller strings of certain length

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

If 
i have this string:

```
"0110100001100101011011000110110001101111"
```

How can I divide it at every eighth character into smaller strings, and put it into a list, so that it looks like this?:

```
['01101000','01100101','01101100','01101100','01101111']
```

So far, I can't figure out how this would be possible.

I should mention, since my strings are in binary so the length is always a multiple of 8.

Comment: You can easily modify the answers given on the duplicate to handle strings instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't think the answers for that other question contain the most elegant way to solve the specific problem at hand. How easily adjustable those answers are depends on the python-experience of the OP.

Comment: @timgeb [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9475241/3001761) is arguably closer, but is also closed as a duplicate!

Comment: @jonrsharpe ah yes, that would indeed be a better fit!

Comment: @timgeb I didn't realise you could close as duplicate of a duplicate!

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh, you can? I wouldn't know. In case you were being sarcastic, I just would not have closed that other duplicate question as a duplicate to begin with. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> mystr = "0110100001100101011011000110110001101111"
>>> [mystr[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(mystr), 8)]
['01101000', '01100101', '01101100', '01101100', '01101111']
```

The solution uses a so called list comprehension ([this](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) seems to be a pretty decent tutorial) and is doing basically the same as Aleph's answer, just in one line.

Comment: If you are interested in how this answer works, google Python List Comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

```
t=[]
for i in range(len(yourstring)/8):
    t.append(yourstring[i*8: (i+1)*8])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use re

```
import re

In [21]: s="0110100001100101011011000110110001101111"

In [22]: re.findall('.{8}',s)
Out[22]: ['01101000', '01100101', '01101100', '01101100', '01101111']
```

As your strings only contain digits we can use  `.`  to match any character.

You can also explicitly use the `\d{8}` which matches 8 digits in a low.

```
In [23]: In [22]: re.findall('\d{8}',s)
Out[23]: ['01101000', '01100101', '01101100', '01101100', '01101111']
```