# Suggestions to split a string into substring

Tags: python

I want to split `"ranganath"` into something like

```
"ra"
"ng"
"an"
"at"
"h"
```

using Python. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplcate of [Split python string every nth character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character)

Comment: `s = "ranganath"; str_split = lambda word, step: [ word[i:i+step] for i in range(0, len(word), step) ]; str_split(s, 2)` > ['ra', 'ng', 'an', 'at', 'h']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
x = 'ranganath'
[ x[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0,len(x),2) ]
```