# python slicing substrings or strings

Tags: python, string, substring, slice

If I have a string `'banana peel'` and I want to break it down to a width of 3 characters as in:

```
'ban'
'ana'
'pee'
'l'
```

How would I go about that? How would I remove the space/whitespace between 'banana' and 'peel' that is in the middle of the string and create the results above?

Only things that come to mind are things like `list()` and `strip()`

Comment: Removing the spaces is simple enough with `s = s.replace(" ", "")`. As for the second question, does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character) address your issue?

Comment: You want it in 3-character chunks, excluding whitespace?

Comment: yes just 3 characters with no spaces

Answer (score 1):

Just like this:

```
string = "banana peel"
string = string.replace(" ", "")
results = []
for i in range(0, len(string), 3):
    results.append(string[i:i + 3])
print(results)
```

`replace(" ", "")` replaces all the spaces with nothing, giving `bananapeel`. `range(0, len(string), 3)` will give a list of numbers from `0` to the length of the string with an interval of 3. Each set gets added to the array for you to print in the end.

Comment: all righty then. the `results.append(string[i:i + 3])` is basically the same as: `results.append(string[0:0 + 3])` in the first run? I am fairly new to slicing.

Comment: Yes, it'll give you all the items from 0 inclusive to 3 exclusive, ie the 0th 1st and 2nd items.

Comment: oooh thanks man. Yes I remember in slicing the last number basically means," up to but not including"

Comment: You could also use a list comprehension instead of the for loop+append: `[string[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(string), 3)]`

Comment: true but that is a little too advanced for me at the momment

Comment: i am coming from a PHP background where there is no such thing as list comprehension