# split python string every nth character (string and nth character are in lists)

Tags: python, string, list, split, numbers

I need something like this for my code:
[Split python string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character/9475354?noredirect=1#comment58106398_9475354)

In my case however; n are numbers within nested lists, and the strings I want to split are also within nested lists.

```
myList = [["'hello''my name'"],["'is Michael'"],["'and'", "'I like''apples'"]]

nList = [[7,9],[12],[5,8,8]
```

I want to get something like this:

```
myNewList = [["'hello'","'my name'"],["'is Michael'"],["'and'", "'I like'","'apples"]]
```

i.e I want to split the string by lengths corresponding to the numbers in `nList`.

I tried using a similar solution to the link I posted above:

My attempt:

```
myNewList = [myList[sum(nList[:i]):sum(nList[:i+1])] for i in range(len(nList))]
```

but it doesn't really match my case.

EDIT:

Note, I do not want to use `split` after each quote, however it is acceptable to offer it as a solution.  The numbers vary and this is a simplified scenario that I am using to allude to my situation with XML data handling/writing.

Comment: can you please explain the meaning of the values in `nList` ? Are they correct for the given example?

Comment: Lengths of the pieces to be grabbed.

Comment: What is the higher purpose behind this?  Since all of the desired phrases are already delimited by single quotes, I don't see the purpose in having the lengths in another list.  Just use **split("''")** on the original entries.

Comment: @Pynchia The values for nList are correct for the example. I double checked.

Comment: @Prune This is simplified scenario, of course.  But if you must know, I am extracting text from elements in an XML document and appending them into nested lists (each nest represents each 'step', or block in the XML).  The text must be separated by a certain number of characters, and these numbers are extracted from another element in the same XML block (therefore the numbers are nested as well).

Comment: @Prune splitting on `''` will give you elements alternating `'` as a prefix and suffix on successive elements. A regex may well be a better solution instead of the list of lenghts

Comment: I need a clarification.  The last element of **myList** has two elements instead of one.  However, the last element of nList has a simple sequence of three integers.  Is the structure not directly applicable?

Comment: exactly, the elements in `myList` are not homogeneous/coherent.

Comment: @Prune Yes, that's correct. The structure is not directly applicable.

Comment: I'd suggest using lxml `import lxml` for extracting elements from xml in a clean way

Comment: @MikeIssa I have a solution in case the elements in `myList` are lists containing a single string, as in the first two elements

Comment: @Ramast Please try and offer a solution to the problem posted, not my situation at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for the case where the structures *are* compatible.  Part of your original problem was a missing subscript: each element of mlList is a sub-list that contains a list of strings.  I've concatenated the final list and inserted the **[0]** subscript, now redundant.

Is this close enough to get you moving?  If not, I can add the necessary **''.join** to finish the job, but it's even uglier than this.

I, too, recommend that you employ an xml parsing tool and regular expressions.  This has been a lovely exercise, but it's not particularly maintainable.

```
myList = [["'hello''my name'"], ["'is Michael'"], ["'and''I like''apples'"]]
nList = [[7, 9], [12], [5, 8, 8]]
myNewList = [[myList[phrase][0][sum(nList[phrase][:spl]):sum(nList[phrase][:spl+1])]
              for spl in range(len(nList[phrase]))]
              for phrase in range(len(myList))]

print myNewList
```

---

Never mind; it was a trivial addition to my attempt above:

```
myList = [["'hello''my name'"], ["'is Michael'"], ["'and'", "'I like''apples'"]]
nList = [[7, 9], [12], [5, 8, 8]]
myNewList = [[''.join(myList[phrase])[sum(nList[phrase][:spl]):sum(nList[phrase][:spl+1])]
              for spl in range(len(nList[phrase]))]
              for phrase in range(len(myList))]

print myNewList
```

Output:

```
[["'hello'", "'my name'"], ["'is Michael'"], ["'and'", "'I like'", "'apples'"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res = []
for word, nums in zip(myList, nList):
    row = []
    curr = 0
    for offset in nums:
        row.append(word[0][curr:curr+offset])
        curr += offset
    res.append(row)

print(res)
```

Untested though.