# How to split a string into a fixed number of parts in Python?

Tags: python, string, split

I know the method [`textwrap.wrap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap), but this method splits a string to a fixed length for each part, but I'm looking for a function in python that splits the string the string into fixed num of parts.

For example:`string = "Hello, my name is foo"` 
and `foo(string, 7)` 
returns `['Hel', 'lo,', ' my', ' na', 'me ', 'is ', 'foo']`

Algorithmically, I know how to implement this method, but I want to know if there a module that provides it or a "magic function" in the regex module that answers this problem...

Comment: @Stidgeon I mentioned that I don't want the textwrap.wrap method :)

Comment: How do you want it to be handled when the string cannot be divided evenly?  For example if the string length is 9 and you want 4 parts do you want the parts to have lengths [3, 2, 2, 2]?  Do you want an error.  Do you want the bigger piece at the beginning or end?

Comment: Voted to reopen because the linked question asked for evenly sized chunks where this question asks for a particular number of chunks.

Comment: You could `textwrap.wrap(your_string, len(your_string)/number_of_chunks)`, depending on how you want to manage cases when the string cannot be divided in `number_of_chunks` parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach can be using `re`.

```
import re
string = "Hello, my name is foo"
def foo(string, parts):
    x=len(string)/parts
    print re.findall(r".{"+str(x)+r"}|.+?$",string)

foo(string,7)
```

Output:`['Hel', 'lo,', ' my', ' na', 'me ', 'is ', 'foo']`

Comment: `foo(string,6)` returns the same result as `foo(string,7)`.  `foo(string,5)` leaves off the last letter of the sentence.  (Temporary downvote until fixed.  Sorry.)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski fixed.............foo(6) and foo(7) will be same .you can have `3.5` letters

Comment: Giving one extra item when the string is not evenly divisible is a surprising result.  You may want to call it out in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if any module does this... but I feel compelled to say that the problem here is basically [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks), except you have strings instead of lists. But the most pythonic way there should also be the most pythonic here, I suppose, and it's a good thing if you can avoid `re`. So here is the solution (not sure what you want if the string cannot be evenly divided by the number of parts; assuming you simply discard the "remainder"):

```
# python 3 version
def foo(string, n):
    part_len = -(-len(string) // n)  # same as math.ceil(len(string) / n)
    return [''.join(x) for x in zip(*[iter_str] * part_len)]
```

Thus:

```
>>> s = "Hello, my name is foo"
>>> foo(s, 7)
['Hel', 'lo,', ' my', ' na', 'me ', 'is ', 'foo']
>>> foo(s, 6)
['Hell', 'o, m', 'y na', 'me i', 's fo']
```

Now admittedly having `foo(s, 6)` return a list of length 5 is somewhat surprising. Maybe you want to raise an exception instead. If you want to keep the remainder, then use `zip_longest`

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def foo2(string, n, pad=''):
    part_len = -(-len(string) // n)
    return [''.join(x) for x in zip_longest(*[iter(string)] * part_len, fillvalue=pad)]

>>> foo2(s, 6)
['Hell', 'o, m', 'y na', 'me i', 's fo', 'o']
>>> foo2(s, 6, pad='?')
['Hell', 'o, m', 'y na', 'me i', 's fo', 'o???']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a builtin, but I think you could do it with regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477447/1342445

In that case your function generates the regex from the len(input) / int(parts) of the string, and raises an error if it's not divisible by the input. Would be much simpler with undefined remainder behavior :)

I think it would look something like:

```
import re


def split_into(string: str, parts: int):
    if (len(string) % parts) != 0:
        raise NotImplementedError('string is not divisible by # parts')

    chunk_size = len(string) / parts
    regex = '.'*chunk_size
    return re.findall(regex, string)
```

Comment: Being evenly divisible is quite the limitation, but at least you call it out.

Comment: Indeed, but the answer becomes more nuanced when you have a remainder. How do you distribute it? Chunk size becomes dynamic, rather than fixed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution to this problem...

```
# split text to parts                                                           
def split_to_parts(txt,parts):
  # return array
  ret=[]
  # calculate part length
  part_len=int(len(txt)/parts)
  # iterate and fill the return array
  for i in range(parts):
    # divide the text
    piece=txt[part_len*i:part_len*(i+1)]
    # add it to the return array
    ret.append(piece)
  # return the array
  return(ret)

txt = "Hello, my name is foo"
parts=7    
split_to_parts(txt,parts)

# output:
# ['Hel', 'lo,', ' my', ' na', 'me ', 'is ', 'foo']
```