# Chunk long string into 513 character chunks | Python 3.3

Tags: python, string

I need to read a .txt file with python 3.3 line by line and split the length of characters (format: MEHSAOSHAHSHSUDO....) into 513 character chunks.
My code works for the first line however the nextline does not work and I cannot work out why.

I am also confused on how to get the code to repeat the nextline function until the end of the file. The file is around 500 lines long.

This is what I have so far:

```
with open('bsxlength.txt' , 'r') as string:
    first_line = string.readline()
    n = 513
    print [first_line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(first_line), n)]
    next_line = string.readline(+2)
    n = 513
    print [next_line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(next_line), n)]
```

Thankyou

The ultimate goal is to make it split the lines into 513 chunks and if there is not enough for a chunk e.g. the line is 600 letters long to count back the appropriote amount of letters (e.g. 87) and make a new chunk. But one step at a time eh

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
next_line = string.readline(+2)
```

means "read a maximum of 2 characters from the current line", not "read the second line". 
You also don't have to manually repeat the same commands for each line - just use a loop:

```
with open('bsxlength.txt' , 'r') as string:
    n = 513
    for line in string:
        print [line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(line), n)]
```

Now back to your initial approach: The optional parameter `size` that `.readline()` takes specifies the number of characters that should at most be read from the current line. So you can use that to achieve your goal:

```
with open('bsxlength.txt' , 'r') as string:
    result = []
    while True:
        chunk = string.readline(513)
        if chunk:
            result.append(chunk)
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! Any clue on how to countback at all (see edit one)

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped; it should be `for line in string`, not `file`. See my edit.

Comment: Probably a silly question but how do I get that to print (I am using Canopy Enthought (for lack of any other software)) and it seems to only display the  output when the term print is used.

Comment: and will this leave any line that are less than 513 characters long untouched.As I only need to split those that are more. Any smaller fragments that occur naturally are still needed.

Comment: You could always just `print(chunk)` during the loop or `print(result)` afterwards. And no, it won't discard shorter lines - as I explained above, `size` specifies the *upper* limit of characters to be read from the current line.