# Python Split string in a certain length

Tags: python, string, split

I have this situation: I got a string that I want to split every X characters. My problem is that the split method only splits the string based on a string such as:

```
a = 'asdeasxdasdqw'
print a.split('x')

>>>['asdeasx', 'dasdqw']
```

What I need is something similar to:

[pseudocode]

```
paragraph = 'my paragraph'

split_offset = 4
print paragraph.split(split_offset)

>>> ['my pa', 'ragraph']
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is called *slicing*:

```
>>> paragraph[:5], paragraph[5:]
('my pa', 'ragraph')
```

To answer the "split every X characters" question, you would need a loop:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> [paragraph[i: i + x] for i in range(0, len(paragraph), x)]
['my pa', 'ragra', 'ph']
```

There are more solutions to this though, see:

- [Split python string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character)
- [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)