# How to split python string every nth-1 + nth char

Tags: python

For example, suppose we have a string:

```
'abcdefg'
```

And we need to get a list like this:

```
['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef', 'fg']
```

we should not use any kind of library

Here is my solution:

```
def str_split(s):
    s = iter(s)
    ch1=''
    ch2=''
    chars_list=[]
    while True:
        try:
            ch1 = ch2 or next(s)
            ch2 = next(s)
            chars_list.append(ch1 + ch2)
        except:
            break
    return chars_list
```

I wonder is there a better solution? Maybe it is possible to use list comprehension like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9475354/1845896)?

Comment: @ErikR Seems to me that these chunks here are overlapping...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
chars_list = [ch1 + ch2 for ch1, ch2 in zip(s, s[1:])]
```

More generally, if you need a solution for any `n`:

```
n = 3
chars_list = [s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s) - n + 1, n - 1)]
# ['abc', 'cde', 'efg']
```

Comment: zip works well. It is a very elegant and powerful solution.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (hacky) solution:

```
def str_split(s):
    return [s[start:end] for start, end in enumerate(range(2, len(s)+1))]
```

Delgan's zipping solution seems more elegant though :)