# Split a string into a list with parts of N characters

Tags: python, string, parsing

I'm very new to python and was wondering what the most pythonic/easy way is to split a string into a list with parts of N characters.

I've come across this:

```
>>>s = "foobar"
>>>list(s)
['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']
```

which is how I can turn a string into a list of characters, but what I would want is to have a method that would look like this:

```
>>>def splitInNSizedParts(s, n):
```

where

```
>>>print(splitInNSizedParts('foobar', 2))
['fo', 'ob', 'ar']
```

Comment: There are also some good ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character).

Answer (score 1):

```
import textwrap
print textwrap.wrap("foobar", 2)
```

Then your function will be :

```
def splitInNSizedParts(s, n):
     return textwrap.wrap(s, n)
```

Comment: Thanks! Just 

    textwrap.wrap(s, n)

will do!