# How can I print output with a defined number of characters in each line with python?

Tags: python-2.7

I used `textwrap.fill (textwrap.fill(text, 6))` to limit each line in only 6 characters, but there is a problem with using this command because my purpose is go to new line exact at 6 character, I mean:

for example using `textwrap.fill(I am a student, 8)`:

what I want:

```
   (I am a s
          tudent)
```

output:

```
(I am a
    student)
```

Comment: for example using textwrap.fill(I am a student, 8): what I want: line1= (I am a s), line2= (tudent); output: line1= (I am a), line2= (student)

Comment: textwrap is designed to do exactly the opposite of what you are trying to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split python string every nth character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character)

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
>>> text = 'I am a student, 8'
>>> text = 'I am a student'
>>> for i in range(0, len(text), 8):
...     print text[i:i+8]
...
I am a s
tudent
```

`for i in range(0, len(text), 8)` means "Give me numbers starting at 0, incrementing by 8 at a time, and ending before the length of the text."

**EDIT**

If you want the value in a single string:

```
>>> wrapped = "\n".join(text[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(text), 8))
>>> wrapped
'I am a s\ntudent'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help