# Split strings with specified step in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string in python without white space and I want python to split this string for every 3 letters so like `'antlapcap'`,
For example would be `['ant', 'lap', 'cap']` is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if theres a more efficient way of doing it but
,try:

```
string = "antlapcap"
list = []
i = 0
for i in range(i,len(string)):
    word =string[i:i+3] 
    list.append(word)
    i=i+3
j = list
b =j[::3]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the string, adding to a string variable until it  reaches a certain length, then append the string to a list. eg.

```
def split_at_nth(string, split_size):
    s = ''
    res = []
    for char in string:
        s += char
        if len(s) == split_size:
            res.append(s)
            s = ''
    return res

s = 'antlapcap'
print(split_at_nth(s, 3)) # prints ['ant', 'lap', 'cap']
```

Another option would be to use a series of list comprehensions:

```
def split_at_nth(string, split_size):
    res = [c for c in string]
    res = [sub for sub in zip(*[iter(res)]*3)]
    res = [''.join(tup) for tup in res]
    return res

s = 'antlapcap'
print(split_at_nth(s, 3)) # prints ['ant', 'lap', 'cap']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to do it.

```
>>> a="abcdefghi"
>>> x=[]
>>> while len(a) != 0:
...  x.append(a[:3])
...  a=a[3:]
... 
>>> a
''
>>> x
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

This simply appends to the list `x` the first 3 characters of the string `a`, then redefines `a` to be everything in `a` except the first 3 characters and so on until `a` is exhausted.

With a hat tip to user @vlk ([Split python string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character)), although I have altered the `while` statement