# python regular expression split function issue

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm using `python2` and I want to get rid of these empty strings in the output of the following python regular expression:

```
import re
x = "010101000110100001100001"
print re.split("([0-1]{8})", x)
```

and the output is this :

```
['', '01010100', '', '01101000', '', '01100001', '']
```

I just want to get this output:

```
['01010100', '01101000', '01100001']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way:

```
print filter(None, re.split("([0-1]{8})", x))
```

Answer (score 4):

Regex probably isn't what you want to use in this case.  It seems that you want to just split the string into groups of *n* (8) characters.

I poached an answer from [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character)

```
def split_every(n, s):
    return [ s[i:i+n] for i in xrange(0, len(s), n) ]

split_every(8, "010101000110100001100001")
Out[2]: ['01010100', '01101000', '01100001']
```

Comment: I actually made another code similar to this and I didn't get to know the Dynamic looping stuff yet, but it's really awesome :D

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
x = "010101000110100001100001"
l = re.split("([0-1]{8})", x)
l2 = [i for i in l if i]
```

out:

```
['01010100', '01101000', '01100001']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what is [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) for. It is split string using regular expression as separator.

If you need to find all matches try use findall instead:

```
import re
x = "010101000110100001100001"
print(re.findall("([0-1]{8})", x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print([a for a in re.split("([0-1]{8})", x) if a != ''])
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your regex approach, you can simply use a filter to get your desired output.

```
import re
x = "010101000110100001100001"
unfiltered_list = re.split("([0-1]{8})", x)
print filter(None, unfiltered_list)
```

If you run this, you should get:

```
['01010100', '01101000', '01100001']
```