# Python String into 8 byte Array

Tags: php, python, arrays, string, bitwise-operators

My problem is to convert a string in python into an array in the following way. I have to split the string into 8byte parts. I didn't find anything like this online. Basically, I want to create the following PHP code in python:

```
$eight_byte_packages_array=str_split($data, 8);
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split python string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP function [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

> will split into bytes, rather than characters when dealing with a multi-byte encoded string.

If you want to simulate this function in Python 3 first you have to convert strings to bytes.

```
def str_split(string, length):
    byte_string = string.encode('utf-8')
    return [byte_string[i:i+length] for i in range(0, len(byte_string), length)]

str_split("This is a test.", 8)
>>> [b'This is ', b'a test.']

str_split("これはテストです。", 8)
>>> [b'\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x8c\xe3\x81',
     b'\xaf\xe3\x83\x86\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3',
     b'\x83\x88\xe3\x81\xa7\xe3\x81\x99',
     b'\xe3\x80\x82']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!