# Given a string in python, how would i split at nth byte, and perform an action with each chunk automatically?

Tags: python, string, shellcode, chunks

```
buf = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";
```

Given this shellcode string (just an example), I would like to split into multiple chunks of nth size.

Once its been split, given unknown nth number of chunks, i would then like it to automatically perform an fuction such as

```
os.system("echo " + chunk[1] + ">>/tmp/final")
os.system("echo " + chunk[2] + ">>/tmp/final")
```

but, without specifying each action each time, and not knowing the number of chunks that its been split into

Comment: are you planning to encode and decode it into bytearray, or do you just want to divide the string at every n characters?

Comment: Just want to divide the string at every nth character, then have complete an action with how ever many unknown chunks repeatedly, as my example.

Comment: This is a nice way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9475538/15890

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the below code helps you, it divides the string at every nth character:

```
nbuf = [buf[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(buf), n)]
for st in nbuf:
    cmdk = 'os.system("echo "' + st + '">>/tmp/final")'
    subprocess.call(cmdk,shell=True)
```

Comment: Don't loop over the indexes (you're missing a `range` for that anyway), just loop over the chunks directly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment added the changes