# Not able to convert HEX to ASCII in python 3.6.3

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, python-3.6, decoding

I tried below methods, but no luck.

method 1:

var contains the hex value

```
bytes.fromhex(var).decode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

method 2:

```
codecs.decode(var,"hex")
```

This is returning me in bytes, not in ASCII.

Can someone help on this conversion?

Comment: In the comment to one of the answers you pasted the actual value of `var`. This hex string can't be ASCII-encoded as it contains hex values out of ASCII range. The error message is valid.

Comment: but with python 2.7.3 i am able to convert it with this method (var.decode("hex"))

Comment: with python 2.7.3 this is the result >>> var = var.decode('hex')
>>> type(var)
<type 'str'> I cannot paste the var ouput as its too long,but it works.

Comment: @CoolNetworking, so do you use P 2.7 or 3.6? There is a huge difference in working with strings

Comment: My question clearly states it "Not able to convert HEX to ASCII in python 3.6.3".With py 2.7 i am able to get it working

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
chr(var)
```

This should give you the character for an ASCII code.

Comment: how will that help as var contains hex value? This is my hex value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

Comment: In that case, var is a string with a hex coded value?
You could try to get integer values with int(var, 16), but you will need to split var into tuples of two characters.

Comment: this is what var contains  'DB91132598CCBF76AE668B4B085176BB192775221FDBB50FCE1C3‌​927C077EAF1E3DAC4C8A‌​8E8028C3F7295EF8157C‌​ED597A36EF1C3BFA4514‌​77BFF32EEB1806C2CC04‌​42585197A2BCD2C43921‌​47AADB93066D0BA5AB6D‌​BFD3F6FCEB7073AE61A5‌​D4AA8ABCBCFF4EEBD1A1‌​655689BFD7EAB82D77BF‌​7224F75FBCD323C9B9FA‌​9C0B7D799180878A81D5‌​D07CF05BE39EEF989B2F‌​C3077997D2C2F1162E5B‌​47D99E4B415BC8CE5C75‌​5476931BD8ED14B5FCEC‌​1C8C654515946AB7860B‌​BBEE7DCCFDAA7AA410FF‌​65352B153B58728D5781‌​4C610F825286D830C308‌​429BDCF1167887B125EF‌​B2FA34B3DEACD329F576‌​74C071BEF6C9CEAC0C7F‌​ABB587A1D6F8B4D0B53'

Comment: @CoolNetworking add this and the desired output into your question

Answer (score 1):

As it follows from the question I assume using Python 3x.
 
The reason of your error is the fact, that you try to decode with ASCII the byte `'0xdb'` which has the value above 127.
You just can't do that - there is no such a byte value in ASCII encoding.
Your options are:
1. Ignore decode errors:

```
>>> u = 'DB91132598CC' # unicode
>>> b = codecs.decode(u,"hex") # bytes
>>> b
b'\xdb\x91\x13%\x98\xcc'
>>> result = b.decode("ascii", errors="ignore") # unicode
>>> result
'\x13%'
```

2. Use different encoding:

```
>>> result = b.decode("cp1252") # for example 
>>> result
'Û‘\x13%˜Ì'
```

If you want only ASCII chars in the result use option #1.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> var = int('7A', 16) #var is an integer now
>>> chr(var) #int value to char
'z'
```

This solution is only for one character. You have to split the string and convert all hex values seperated. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character) how to split it.

Comment: my var contains a string of hex value.how will that help?

Comment: chr(0xf8) is NOT an ASCII char since 0xf8 == 248 and this is above 128. actually, this char is: `import unicodedata` => `print(unicodedata.name(chr(0xf8)))` => `LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH STROKE`

Comment: Thanks @MaximTitarenko

Comment: @MaximTitarenko no luck.you can try with my value of var as shown below and let me know.

Comment: Your hex values are not ascii. Do you realy want do convert them in ascii? It seens for me that you try to convert an encrypted code.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
 codecs.decode(codecs.decode(var,'hex'),'ascii')
```

Comment: yes but it gives me below error >>> codecs.decode(codecs.decode(var,'hex'),'ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
codecs.decode(var,"hex")
```

in Python 2.7 results with `str`:

```
'\xdb\x91\x13%\x98\xcc\xbfv\xaef\x8bK\x08Qv\xbb\x19\'u"\x1f\xdb\xb5\x0f\xce\x1c9\'\xc0w\xea\xf1\xe3\xda\xc4\xc8\xa8\xe8\x02\x8c?r\x95\xef\x81W\xce\xd5\x97\xa3n\xf1\xc3\xbf\xa4QG{\xff2\xee\xb1\x80l,\xc0D%\x85\x19z+\xcd,C\x92\x14z\xad\xb90f\xd0\xbaZ\xb6\xdb\xfd?o\xce\xb7\x07:\xe6\x1a]J\xa8\xab\xcb\xcf\xf4\xee\xbd\x1a\x16Uh\x9b\xfd~\xab\x82\xd7{\xf7"Ou\xfb\xcd2<\x9b\x9f\xa9\xc0\xb7\xd7\x99\x18\x08x\xa8\x1d]\x07\xcf\x05\xbe9\xee\xf9\x89\xb2\xfc0w\x99},/\x11b\xe5\xb4}\x99\xe4\xb4\x15\xbc\x8c\xe5\xc7UGi1\xbd\x8e\xd1K_\xce\xc1\xc8\xc6TQYF\xabx`\xbb\xbe\xe7\xdc\xcf\xda\xa7\xaaA\x0f\xf6SR\xb1S\xb5\x87(\xd5x\x14\xc6\x10\xf8%(m\x83\x0c0\x84)\xbd\xcf\x11g\x88{\x12^\xfb/\xa3K=\xea\xcd2\x9fWgL\x07\x1b\xefl\x9c\xea\xc0\xc7\xfa\xbbXz\x1do\x8bM\x0bS'
```

and in Python 3.6 `bytes`:

```
b'\xdb\x91\x13%\x98\xcc\xbfv\xaef\x8bK\x08Qv\xbb\x19\'u"\x1f\xdb\xb5\x0f\xce\x1c9\'\xc0w\xea\xf1\xe3\xda\xc4\xc8\xa8\xe8\x02\x8c?r\x95\xef\x81W\xce\xd5\x97\xa3n\xf1\xc3\xbf\xa4QG{\xff2\xee\xb1\x80l,\xc0D%\x85\x19z+\xcd,C\x92\x14z\xad\xb90f\xd0\xbaZ\xb6\xdb\xfd?o\xce\xb7\x07:\xe6\x1a]J\xa8\xab\xcb\xcf\xf4\xee\xbd\x1a\x16Uh\x9b\xfd~\xab\x82\xd7{\xf7"Ou\xfb\xcd2<\x9b\x9f\xa9\xc0\xb7\xd7\x99\x18\x08x\xa8\x1d]\x07\xcf\x05\xbe9\xee\xf9\x89\xb2\xfc0w\x99},/\x11b\xe5\xb4}\x99\xe4\xb4\x15\xbc\x8c\xe5\xc7UGi1\xbd\x8e\xd1K_\xce\xc1\xc8\xc6TQYF\xabx`\xbb\xbe\xe7\xdc\xcf\xda\xa7\xaaA\x0f\xf6SR\xb1S\xb5\x87(\xd5x\x14\xc6\x10\xf8%(m\x83\x0c0\x84)\xbd\xcf\x11g\x88{\x12^\xfb/\xa3K=\xea\xcd2\x9fWgL\x07\x1b\xefl\x9c\xea\xc0\xc7\xfa\xbbXz\x1do\x8bM\x0bS'
```

The reason is that in Python 2.7

```
str == bytes #True
```

while in Python 3.6

```
str == bytes #False
```

Python 2 strings are byte strings, while Python 3 strings are unicode strings. Both results are actually the same, but byte string in Python 3 is of type `bytes` not `str` and literal representation is prefixed with `b`.
This has nothing to do with ASCII encoding as none of the output variables (regardless of Python version) is ASCII encoded.
Moreover on Python 2.7 you will also get this error:

```
codecs.decode(var, 'hex').decode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I actually pasted it from Python 2.7 interpreter but you can check yourself.
Your output string can't be decoded with `ascii` codec in any version of Python because it's simply not `ascii` encoded string in any case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually, I want an equivalent of this decoding method (var.decode("hex")) in 3.6 version which works fine in 2.7  and gives me the expected result.

Comment: @CoolNetworking the result is the same. Bytestring. Only notation is different since Python 3 has Unicode string as `str` type.