# Split string every nth character from the right?

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

I have different very large sets of files which I'd like to put in different subfolders. I already have an consecutive ID for every folder I want to use.
I want to split the ID **from the right** to always have 1000 folders in the deeper levels.

**Example**:

id: `100243` => resulting_path: `'./100/243'`

id: `1234567890` => resulting path: `'1/234/567/890'`

I found [Split string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character), but all solutions are from left to right and I also did not want to import another module for one line of code.

My current (working) solution looks like this:

```
import os

base_path = '/home/made'
n=3    # take every 'n'th from the right
max_id = 12345678900
test_id = 24102442

# current algorithm
str_id = str(test_id).zfill(len(str(max_id)))
ext_path = list(reversed([str_id[max(i-n,0):i] for i in range(len(str_id),0,-n)]))
print(os.path.join(base_path, *ext_path))
```

Output is: `/home/made/00/024/102/442`

The current algorithm looks awkward and complicated for the simple thing I want to do. 
I wonder if there is a better solution. If not it might help others, anyway.

**Update:**

I really like Joe Iddons solution. Using .join and mod makes it faster and more readable.

In the end I decided that I never want to have a `/`in front. To get rid of the preceeding `/`in case `len(s)%3`is zero, I changed the line to

```
'/'.join([s[max(0,i):i+3] for i in range(len(s)%3-3*(len(s)%3 != 0), len(s), 3)])
```

Thank you for your great help!

**Update 2:**

If you are going to use `os.path.join` (like in my previous code) its even simpler since `os.path.join`takes care of the format of the args itself:

```
ext_path = [s[0:len(s)%3]] + [s[i:i+3] for i in range(len(s)%3, len(s), 3)]
print(os.path.join('/home', *ext_path))
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to round up the "max ID length" to the nearest multiple of n? That is, is it OK if the *first* path segment is always n characters long?

Comment: Here is a starting point... Modifying the answer from the link you provided to this `[line[i-n:i] for i in range(len(line), 0, -n)]` gets you `['890', '567', '234', '']`

Comment: @DanielPryden: That would not be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adapt the answer you linked, and use the beauty of `mod` to create a nice little `one-liner`:

```
>>> s = '1234567890'
>>> '/'.join([s[0:len(s)%3]] + [s[i:i+3] for i in range(len(s)%3, len(s), 3)])
'1/234/567/890'
```

and if you want this to auto-add the `dot` for the cases like your first example of:

```
s = '100243'
```

then you can <s>just add a mini ternary</s> use `or` as suggested by `@MosesKoledoye`:

```
>>> '/'.join(([s[0:len(s)%3] or '.']) + [s[i:i+3] for i in range(len(s)%3, len(s), 3)])
'./100/243'
```

This method will also be faster than `reversing` the `string` before hand or `reversing` a `list`.

Comment: Instead of the ternary, you can do: `[s[0:len(s)%3] or '.']`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye That's really nice, definitely!

Answer (score 1):

Then if you got a solution for the direction left to right, why not simply reverse the input and output ?

```
str = '1234567890'
str[::-1]
```

Output:

```
'0987654321'
```

You can use the solution you found for left to right and then, you simply need to reverse it again.

Comment: Thanks! I think that's exactly what Serg Anuke did in his answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex and modulo to split the strings into groups of three. This solution should get you started:

```
import re
s = [100243, 1234567890]
final_s = ['./'+'/'.join(re.findall('.{2}.', str(i))) if len(str(i))%3 == 0 else str(i)[:len(str(i))%3]+'/'+'/'.join(re.findall('.{2}.', str(i)[len(str(i))%3:])) for i in s]
```

Output:

```
['./100/243', '1/234/567/890']
```

Comment: *This solution should get you started*. I doubt that. Pretty illegible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> line = '1234567890'
>>> n = 3
>>> rev_line = line[::-1]
>>> out = [rev_line[i:i+n][::-1] for i in range(0, len(line), n)]
>>> ['890', '567', '234', '1']
>>> "/".join(reversed(out))
>>> '1/234/567/890'
```