# how to split a string in python

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string such as `'0111111011111100'` and I want to separate every four characters so here that would be:

```
0111,1110,1100
```

Then I want to replace those with another values.

Here is my code so far, but it doesn't work properly:

Comment: to split string every nth character https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character)

Comment: Do you want your `line` variable to be modified so that in your case to become `line = 'abcd'`?

Comment: Please edit the question to include your expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `list-comprehension` with `string` `indexing`:

```
s = "0111111011111100"
[s[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(s),4)]
```

gives:

```
['0111', '1110', '1111', '1100']
```

and then define a `dictionary` for what you want each `nibble` to translate to:

```
d = {'0111': 'a', '1110': 'b', '1111': 'c', '1100': 'd'}
```

and then you can shove the translating into the `list-comp`:

```
[d[s[i:i+4]] for i in range(0,len(s),4)]
```

which would give:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

and finally use `str.join` to put this back into a `string`, making the entire conversion one-line:

```
''.join(d[s[i:i+4]] for i in range(0,len(s),4))
```

which gives:

```
'abcd'
```

*as a matter of fact, a `generator` expression is being used here as they are more efficient than `list-comprehensions`*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace each group of four digits in string with some value you could use `dict`

```
line='0111111011111100'
lookup = {'0111': 'a', '1110': 'b', '1100': 'c'} # add all combination here
"".join(lookup.get(line[i:i+4], 'D') for i in range(0, len(line), 4)) # 'D' is default value
Out[18]: 'abDc'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line='0111111011111100'
# define a dictionary with nibbles as values
dict = { '0111': 'a', '1110': 'b', '1111': 'c', '1100': 'd'}

# define chunk size
n = 4

# use a list comprehension to split the original string into chunks
key_list = [line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(line), n)]

# use a generator expression to replace keys in the list with
# their dictionary values and join together
key_list = ' '.join(str(dict.get(value, value)) for value in key_list)
print(key_list)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: added some explanatory notes

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might help you:

```
str = "0111111011111100"

n = 4

# Create a list from you string with 4 characters in one element of list.
tmp_list = [str[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(str), n)]
# tmp_list : ['0111', '1110', '1111', '1100']

for n, i in enumerate(tmp_list):
    if tmp_list[n] == "0111":
        tmp_list[n] = "A"
    # elif ....
    # Todo:
    # Populate your if-elif requirements here.   

result_str = ''.join(tmp_list)
```