# How to split integer input in python?

Tags: python, string, split, integer

If you write like

```
n = str(input())

n = n.split()

print(n)
```

That will work. But if you try to do it with integers, you will get

```
`Value Error`.
```

How to do it with int type?

Comment: Please format as code

Comment: Show the error. I'm unable to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Pleas show your simple code.

Comment: to split a string with no delimiter ( like space or comma), have a look at : [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character) ...but, an error cannot be the result of the above code unless the result of input() is not simply an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to separate several numbers? 1 2 3 -> [1, 2, 3]

```
n = str(input())
n = n.split()
numbers = [int(i) for i in n]
print(numbers)
```

Or split a number in numeral? 123 -> [1, 2, 3]

```
n = str(input())
numbers = [int(i) for i in n]
print(numbers)
```

Use Nikhil answer, if you want to split a number with delimiters 1%3 -> [1, 3]

Answer (score 2):

You can split integer value with following ways..

1. list comprehension

   ```
   n = str(input())
   result = [x for x in n]
   print(result)
   ```

2. using list object

   ```
    n = str(input())
    result = [x for x in n]
    print(result)
   ```
3. using map object

   ```
    n = str(input())
    result = list(map(int,n))
    print(result)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this,

```
n = 567
a = str(n).split(YOUR DELIMITER)
```

Like if  YOUR DELIMITER = 6,
Then if i `print(a)` then i get,

```
['5', '7']
```