# how to get input from user in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, input

how can I get this input from user and store it in a list in python?

```
3 4
5 7 3 7 9
2 1 20 3 2
8 1 20 1 1
```

when I use this code `x = input()`
it just receives the 3 and 4.

but i want the output as list below:
[3,4,5, 7, 3, 7, 9, 2, 1, 20, 3, 2, 8, 1, 20, 1, 1]

Comment: There are hundreds of posts and resources that tell you how to take input... why ask? Do you research... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/how-do-i-read-multiple-lines-of-raw-input-in-python & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064817/how-to-split-integer-input-in-python

Comment: then split each line and convert to int - also plenty of ressources for that:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers

Comment: i've searched , i can do it with this code but there is a problem, user must hit the ENTER twice to make the code run :   `from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input
content = []
while True:
    line = raw_input()
    if line:
        content.append(line)
    else:
        break
print(content)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read multiple lines of raw input in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/how-do-i-read-multiple-lines-of-raw-input-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

You can use x = list(map(int, input().split()))