# String tranformation into Clean list of int

Tags: python

I ideally want to turn this `100020630` into `[100,020,630]`
but so far i can only do this `"100.020.630"` into `["100","020","630"]`

```
def fulltotriple(x):
    X=x.split(".")
    return X

print(fulltotriple("192.123.010"))
```

for some additionnal info my goal is no turn ip adresses into bin adresses using this as a first step =)

edit: i have not found any way of getting the list WITHOUT the " " in the list on stack overflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def fulltotriple(data):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(data), 3):
        result.append(int(data[i:i + 3]))
    return (result)


print(fulltotriple("192123010"))
```

output:

```
[192, 123, 10]
```

Comment: there is still a problem the '' remain in the list

Comment: can you explain what you mean by that @PablitoGnp

Comment: i want [192] instead of ["192"] for it to be usable as an int =)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one approach using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
s = '100020630'
[s[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]
# ['100', '020', '630']
```

Comment: there is still a problem the '' remain in the list

Comment: If you want them as integers, use `[int(s[i:i + 3]) for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]` @PablitoGnp

Answer (score 4):

You could use the built-in [`wrap`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/textwrap.html) function:

```py
In [3]: s = "100020630"                                                                                                                                                                                          
In [4]: import textwrap                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
In [6]: textwrap.wrap(s, 3)                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[6]: ['100', '020', '630']
```

> Wraps the single paragraph in text (a string) so every line is at most width characters long. Returns a list of output lines, without final newlines.

If you want a list of `int`s:

```py
[int(num) for num in textwrap.wrap(s, 3)]
```

Outputs:

```
[100, 020, 630]
```

Comment: there is still a problem the '' remain in the list

Comment: You can use a list comprehension to have a list of `int`s. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to handle IP addresses, you are doing it totally wrong.

[IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) is a 24-binary digit number, not a 9-decimal digit. It is splitted for 4 sub-blocks, like: `192.168.0.1`. BUT. In decimal view they all can be 3-digit, or 2-digit, or any else combination. I recommend you to use [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address) standard module:

```
import ipaddress

a = '192.168.0.1'

ip = ipaddress.ip_address(a)
ip.packed
```

will return you the packed binary format:

`b'\xc0\xa8\x00\x01'`

If you want to convert your IPv4 to binary format, you can use this command:

`''.join(bin(i)[2:] for i in ip.packed)`

It will return you this string:

`'110000001010100001'`

Comment: thanks how do i put this in a list of 4 group of 8 number

Answer (score 3):

Use regex to find all matches of triplets `\d{3}`

```
import re

str = "100020630"

def fulltotriple(x):
    pattern = re.compile(r"\d{3}")
    return [int(found_match) for found_match in pattern.findall(x)]


print(fulltotriple(str))
```

Outputting:

```
[100, 20, 630]
```

Comment: there is still a problem the '' remain in the list

Comment: @PablitoGnp I didnt get you sorry, care to explain

Comment: i want [192] instead of ["192"] for it to be usable as an int =)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `wrap` which is a inbuilt function in python

```
from textwrap import wrap

def fulltotriple(x):
    x = wrap(x, 3)
    return x

print(fulltotriple("100020630"))
```

Outputs:

```
['100', '020', '630']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use python built-ins for this:

```py
text = '100020630'

# using wrap

from textwrap import wrap
wrap(text, 3)
>>> ['100', '020', '630']


# using map/zip

map(''.join, zip(*[iter(text)]*3))
>>> ['100', '020', '630']
```

Comment: there is still a problem the '' remain in the list

Comment: @PablitoGnp You can do [int(x) for x in wrap(text, 3)] or look at Yatu's answer