# ValueError invalid literal for int() with base 2: '' in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I'm trying to get a string, `jJ`, as input and then converting each character to it's 6 bit binary form using the mapping given in a and concatenating them and returning it in `mapFirst(string)`. That is, `jJ` becomes `100011001001`.

In `binaryToLetter(string)` I'm taking the returned value and separating it into parts of 8 bits and converting it back to it's character form and concatenated. `100011001001` becomes `00001000` and `11001001`, which are then converted and joined to give `(backspace)É`.

In my code, I'm getting the error :

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
invalid literal for int() with base 2: ''

  File "C:\Users\Sembian\Desktop\exc files new\Ex_Files_Learning_Python\Exercise Files\task_cs\task1.py", line 11, in <genexpr>
    return ''.join( str( int( (binNew[newLen:newLen-i]),2 ) ).replace('0b','').zfill(8) for i in range(0, newLen, n) )
```

The code I used is :

```
from textwrap import wrap
a = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','/']

def mapFirst(string):
   return ''.join(str(bin(ord(chr(a.index(c))))).replace('0b','').zfill(6) for c in string)

def binaryToLetter(binNew):
   newLen = len(str(binNew))          
   n=8
   return ''.join( str( int( (binNew[newLen:newLen-i]),2 ) ).replace('0b','').zfill(8) for i in range(0, newLen, n) )

def main():
   k = 'jJ'
   print("the first binary value is: ",mapFirst(k))
   print("the final decoded value is: ", binaryToLetter(mapFirst(k)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: probably passing an empty string, that's all. But there's too much code here. Reduce this to a [mcve] this is horrible `''.join(str(bin(ord(chr(a.index(c))))).replace('0b','').zfill(6)`

Comment: I'll work on reducing the code, thanks! I checked binNew and it wasn't empty. Which part are you saying might be passing an empty string?

Comment: this slicing produces an empty string everytime:

    `return ''.join( str( int( (binNew[newLen:newLen-i]),2 ) ).replace('0b','').zfill(8) for i in range(0, newLen, n) )`
 because start of slice is >= end of slice

Comment: `range(0, newLen, n)` yields `[0, 8]`.  Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I made start of slice >= end of slice because I wanted it to begin slicing from the right end (since I may have to add '0's in front of the string to make it a multiple of exactly 8 bits). Since this gives an empty string, is there another way to do this? I'm new to python so excuse my mistakes, thanks!

Comment: To illustrate what they're saying type this in the interpreter: int('',2)

Comment: This may be what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character

Comment: I made `binNew[newLen:newLen-i]` as `binNew[newLen-i:newLen]` to make start of slice < end of slice but i'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get something kinda working. For the first part:

```py
def mapFirst(string):
   return ''.join(bin(a.index(c))[2:].zfill(6) for c in string)
```

I have removed a bunch of unnecessary clutter:

1. `ord(chr(x)) == x` (assuming x:int < 256), because `ord` is an inverse of `chr`.
2. `str(bin(x)) == bin(x)`, because `bin` already returns a string.
3. `bin(x).replace('0b', '') == bin(x)[2:]`, because `bin` will always return a string starting with `0b`, so you can use string (list) slicing.

For the second part:

```py
def binaryToLetter(binNew):
   return ''.join(reversed([chr(int(binNew[max(0, i - 8):i], 2))
                            for i in range(len(binNew), 0, -8)]))
```

To break it down a little:

1. I am using `range(len(binNew), -1, -8)` to generate decreasing a sequence from `len(binNew)` to 0 (inclusive) in steps of -8.
2. I am then using the list slicing again to get the 8-bit long chunks from `binNew`, making sure that I don't overshoot the last one (that what the `max()` is for).
3. I am turning these 8 char strings to a number with `int(..., 2)` and turning that number to `chr`.
4. Because I am "chopping" away the 8 long substrings starting from the back, I need to reverse the order. But `reversed` doesn't accept generators, so I change the original generator into a list.

Comment: It's working for some inputs like `jJ` or even `jJy23ujlmjdkfnjflnjrkfk4j` but not for `Y3Jvc3MgYm90aCB0YWJsZXMgc2l4IHRoaXJ0eSBwcm9ncmFtIGFuYWx5c2lzIGluc2VydCAyMTAxMjM0` which is what I have to decode. I'm getting the same error:  ValueError
invalid literal for int() with base 2: '' in this case. I tried giving a few more random inputs, and it works in some cases and not in others. I can't figure out why.

Comment: @SembianBalakrishnan my bad, the range should be `range(len(binNew), 0, -8)`. Edited. The reason why it doesn't work, is that if it perfectly aligned with 8 bit length (ei the original string was multiple of 4 long) it then did a slice [0:0] which will be `""` and that would cause `int` to fail.

Comment: @SembianBalakrishnan but you should be doing `base64.b64decode()` anyway :D