# Split string at a certain point in python

Tags: python

I am trying to split a string at a certain point using `python`

What I want to do is as follows:

let's say we have a string as

```
str = "123456789123456789"
```

I want to break this string in to parts where each part has a length of `5` or less (the last part)

so the output of the above string should look like this:

```
    l: 12345
    r: 67891
    l: 23456
    r: 789
```

This is my code I am trying to do this:

```
            errormsg = "123456789123456789"
            if len(errormsg) > 5 :
                print("yes")
                splitat = 5
                str = errormsg
                l, r = str[:splitat], str[splitat:]
                print("l: " + l)
                print("r: " + r)

                while len(r) > 5:
                    # print("hi")                
                    str = r
                    splitat = 5
                    l, r = str[:splitat], str[splitat:]
                    print("l: " + l)
                    print("r: " + r)
```

But it gives a weird output like this:

```
yes
l: 12345
r: 6789123456789
l: 67891
r: 23456789
l: 23456
r: 789
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: you dont say what you want the output to be? so its hard to say how to fix it. The output you gett is because you keep printing the l and r values after you split them but you never store these

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character)

Comment: The reason is that you give the slice for `r` no end position, so it encompasses the rest of the string

Comment: errormsg = "123456789123456789"
if len(errormsg) > 5 :
    print("yes")
    splitat = 5
    str = errormsg
    l, r = str[:splitat], str[splitat:splitat*2]
    print("l: " + l)
    print("r: " + r)
    
    while len(str) > 5:
        # print("hi")
        splitat = 5
        l, r = str[:splitat], str[splitat:splitat*2]
        str = str[splitat*2:splitat*3]
        print("l: " + l)
        print("r: " + r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
str = "123456789123456789"
splitted_string = []

for i in range(0, len(str), 5):
    splitted_string.append(str[i:i+5])

print(splitted_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use the recipe from the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Comment: `izip`? Is this a eulogy for Python 2, which ends tonight?

Comment: zip if you feel like leaping into the new decade =D