# How do i clean a url using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

When i extract a url, it displays as below

```
https://tv.line.me/v/14985624_%E0%B8%A0%E0%B8%B9%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A5-ep3-6-6-%E0%B8%8A%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%878
```

how do i convert this to more readable format like below in python. The link below is the same as above.

[Link to the image of how the url appears on browser address bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX57G.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "more readable" ? Split at some n characters? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character

Comment: i just updated my question with the image of the URL as it appears in the address bar. I want to convert the string extracted to that format

Comment: Maybe they want to display the special characters?

Comment: ya so when i extract the link, i think the THAI characters in the URL are converted into i think its ACSII equivalent. so i want to convert it back to its original form like shown in the image above

Answer (score 2):

You can use `urllib` module to decode this url

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
url = unquote('https://tv.line.me/v/14985624_%E0%B8%A0%E0%B8%B9%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A5-ep3-6-6-%E0%B8%8A%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%878')

print(url)
```

This will give you the result as follows.

> [https://tv.line.me/v/14985624_ภูตรัตติกาล-ep3-6-6-ช่อง8](https://tv.line.me/v/14985624_%E0%B8%A0%E0%B8%B9%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A5-ep3-6-6-%E0%B8%8A%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%878)

Thank you