# Readable hex dump of bytes

Tags: python

I want to convert a list of bytes as a string of hex values. The list of bytes is a bit long, so I want spaces between the bytes to improve readability. The function `hexlify` as well as `hex` does the job:

```
import binascii
a = [1,2,3,4]
s = binascii.hexlify(bytearray(a))
print s
s = bytes(a).hex()
print s
```

But the result is '01020304'. I want a dump with a space between the bytes like '01 02 03 04'. How can I do this in an efficient way?

**Edit:**
There is also a way to iterate all bytes. Would this be efficient?

```
s = ' '.join('%02x' % i for i in a)
```

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9475354/1174966

Comment: @jdaz That answer generates a list of strings. I want to get one string that can be processed further, e.g. written to a file.

Comment: What version of python are you using? There is a `sep` argument to `bytes.hex` but it is new in 3.8.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [bytes.hex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex) with a separator string:

```
>>> bs = b'Hello world'
>>> bs.hex(sep=' ')
'48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the result

```
import binascii
a = [1,2,3,4]
s = binascii.hexlify(bytearray(a))
s = bytes(a).hex()
iterate = iter(s)
print ' '.join(a+b for a,b in zip(iterate, iterate))
```