# How can i separate in a string in 2

Tags: python

I want to separate a string of numbers into 2 ".", like this.

```
numbers = (12345678910)
numbers = (12.34.56.78.910) 
print(numbers) = 12.34.56.78.910
```

I try with print(".") buts look's ugly

How can i do it? Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi. Are those meant to be strings (with "") or lists?

Comment: Hi! It need to look like = 
12.34.56.78.910

Comment: I see the question has been closed as it has been asked before. Here is one example answer I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9475354/8289095