# How do I transform a text file in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, text, split

I have a text file which contains a text such as: "001232029890"

And I want python to take this text and make a list in this manner:

```
list = [001,232,029,890]
```

That is, to split the text file into segments of n characters (in this case 3) and to put each of those segments in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read in your file as shown in [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp). Afterwards you can split the text on the nth character with `[line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(line), n)]` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character). (Since you left the two zeros in your example I'm assuming that you meant to use strings)

Comment: Actually, the list contains integers. I left the zeros just for emphasis. But I suppose I can convert it using the int function, right?

Comment: Yes, that would be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
def getListOfNChars(inputString, numberOfCharacters):
    resultList = []
    for i in range(0, len(inputString), numberOfCharacters):
        resultList.append(inputString[i : i+numberOfCharacters])
    return resultList

#inputString - The String You Want To Process
#numberOfCharacters - Number Of Characters You Want To Extract At A Time
```