# How to convert a string into a custom base using 2 alphabet chars per letter

Tags: python, algorithm, radix, converters

The functions below convert number `255 (base10)` into `'FF' (base16)` using base16 alphabet `'0123456789ABCDEF'`.

I'm having difficulties figuring out how to modify the functions such that they would use 2 characters of the alphabet per letter so that number `255 (base10)` would convert to `'xFxF' (base16)` using modified base16 alphabet `'x0x1x2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9xAxBxCxDxExF'`.

```py
def v2r(num, alphabet):
  """Convert base 10 number into a string of a custom base (alphabet)."""
  alphabet_length = len(alphabet)
  result = ''
  while num > 0:
    result = alphabet[num % alphabet_length] + result
    num  = num // alphabet_length
  return result


def r2v(data, alphabet):
  """Convert string of a custom base (alphabet) back into base 10 number."""
  alphabet_length = len(alphabet)
  num = 0
  for char in data:
    num = alphabet_length * num + alphabet[:alphabet_length].index(char)
  return num

base16 = v2r(255, '0123456789ABCDEF')
base10 = r2v(base16, '0123456789ABCDEF')
print(base16, base10)
# output: FF 255

# base16 = v2r(255, 'x0x1x2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9xAxBxCxDxExF')
# base10 = r2v(base16, 'x0x1x2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9xAxBxCxDxExF')
# print(base16, base10)
# output: xFxF 255
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet? What were your findings?

Comment: For such a small program, executing the code myself with pen and paper for a small example often helps me to find the problem quite easily.

Comment: @MrSmith42 yeah it's quite a simple concept but I've never really worked with base conversions, so I don't have a complete understanding of the concept itself

Comment: The only thing you have to modify in `v2r` is the line `result = alphabet[num % alphabet_length] + result`. There a several ways to modify it that would work. Good luck!

Comment: Note that the simplest way both for `v2r` and `r2v` is to first split your string into a sequence of length-2 strings. See this related question: [Split strin every nth character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character)

Comment: Here the basics: base conversion:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible workaround. I think your bug came from a confusion with python definition of types and iterables.
I've modified the base 16 alphabet, it is now a list of items. Then I also modified a bit the function to take this into account, and it looks like it works.

```
def v2r(num, alphabet):
    """Convert base 10 number into a string of a custom base (alphabet)."""
    alphabet_length = len(alphabet)
    result = []
    while num > 0:
        result = [alphabet[num % alphabet_length]] + result
        num  = num // alphabet_length
    return result


def r2v(data, alphabet):
    """Convert string of a custom base (alphabet) back into base 10 number."""
    alphabet_length = len(alphabet)
    num = 0
    for char in data:
        num = alphabet_length * num + alphabet.index(char)
    return num

alphabet = [
    'x0','x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7', 'x8',
    'x9', 'xA', 'xB', 'xC', 'xD', 'xE', 'xF'
]
base16 = v2r(255, alphabet)
base10 = r2v(base16, alphabet)
print(''.join(base16), base10)
#  xFxF 255
```

Following the OP's comment:
just declare the following alphabet:

```
hexa = '0123456789abcdef'
alphabet = [
    a+b for a in hexa for b in hexa
]
```

Comment: Did you test it? It looks like `result += [alphabet[num % alphabet_length]]` is appending characters at the end instead of adding them at the beginning; so the output is going to be reversed.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I know why I was so confused. I wanted to make each character to encode 2 bits: `01, 02, 03, ..., FF`, rather than just use a custom char like `xF`  I just didn't explain it well at all...

Comment: @Stef is there a way to modify it so that each character actually encodes 2 bits like that `01, 02, 03, ..., FF`? So that effectively each letter encodes 255 combinations (0 - 255 in base 10)

Comment: @AlekseyHoffman It already does that; you can try by using alphabet `[a+b for a in '0123456789ABCDEF' for b in '0123456789ABCDEF']` which is `['00', '01', '02', '03', ..., 'FE', 'FF']`

Comment: @AlekseyHoffman But as I said, I think the line `result += [alphabet[num % alphabet_length]]` in this answer is wrong and you should instead use the line from your original code. You can test whether it works well or not by trying to convert a number in base 10 using the alphabet `[' 0', ' 1', ' 2', ..., ' 9']`.

Comment: and then `for x in range(1000): y = ''.join(v2r(x, [' 0', ..., ' 9']).split()); if  y != str(x): print(y, x)`

Comment: @Stef you're completely right, I'm editing straight away

Comment: @Stef hmm. guys, it seems like characters don't actually encode 2 bits. I just explained it completely wrong. What I actually need is it to encode 2 bits not just use 2 character as a letter, so that if we have an alphabet of 256 characters long `['00', '01', '02', '03', ... 'FF']` when we encode number 15 I want it actually to return `0F`  and for 16 return `10`, and for 256 return `FF` and only when it actually fills the 2 bits, for the number 257 it should overflow and return 4bits: `00 00`.

Comment: reedited :) it should do what you want it to do now

Comment: @m.raynal thank you, I generated the alphabet in a similar way, but as I explained in the previous comment, I explained the problem incorrectly this algorithm doesn't fill the bits. For number `15` it returns `0F 15` instead of `0F`, it doesn't actually use 256 combinations per letter, it should only return 4 bits `00 00` for the number 256 (or 257?) when it uses all the combinations of 2 bits `['00', '01', '02', '03', ... 'FF']` and overflows to 4 bits

Comment: 256 should be `'0100'` and 255 should be `'FF'`. Presumably this is already the case with @m.raynal 's code.

Answer (score 1):

I sugget to remove 'x' before starting the calucltion, therefore add as a first line of your function

```
alphabet=alphabet.replace('x','')
```

so your functions will work with both systems 'FFF' or 'xFxFxF'.

```
def v2r(num, alphabet):
  """Convert base 10 number into a string of a custom base (alphabet)."""
  alphabet=alphabet.replace('x','') ### added
  alphabet_length = len(alphabet)
  result = ''
  while num > 0:
    result = alphabet[num % alphabet_length] + result
    num  = num // alphabet_length
  return result


def r2v(data, alphabet):
  """Convert string of a custom base (alphabet) back into base 10 number."""
  alphabet=alphabet.replace('x','') ### added
  alphabet_length = len(alphabet)
  num = 0
  for char in data:
    num = alphabet_length * num + alphabet[:alphabet_length].index(char)
  return num
```