# panda series object: cut string into equal chunks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I found a solution to cut a string like `s = '247451517328'` here: [Split string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character) using using more_itertools sliced.
But how can I apply this to a dataframe elegantly? e. g. a dataframe df

```
A    B
1    *N8111111.
2    BC1111111*
3    77N01101.*
```

should become (sliced by every second character)

```
A    B  C  D  E  F
1    *N 81 11 11 1.
2    BC 11 11 11 1*
3    77 N0 11 01 .*
```

I tried

```
from more_itertools import sliced
df.str.sliced('1234567890', 2)
```

but this doesn't work since str has no method 'sliced'.

Comment: maybe try apply? ``df.B.apply(lambda x: sliced(x, 2)``. apply is usually the way to go when using another library within Pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
df[['A']].join(pd.DataFrame(df['B'].str.findall(r'.{2}|.{1}').tolist()))
```

---

```
   A   0   1   2   3   4
0  1  *N  81  11  11  1.
1  2  BC  11  11  11  1*
2  3  77  N0  11  01  .*
```

Answer (score 1):

You solution will work with apply since `slice` takes a single string not a series:

```
from more_itertools import sliced
df[['A']].join(pd.DataFrame(df['B'].apply(lambda x: sliced(x, 2)).tolist()))
```

---

```
   A   0   1   2   3   4
0  1  *N  81  11  11  1.
1  2  BC  11  11  11  1*
2  3  77  N0  11  01  .*
```