# String.Strip is skipping a character the second for loop

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

For some reason after the second loop in my array the code is skipping a character for some reason.

I think here is the problem:

```py
    for word in range(int(len(ShortArray))):
        localString = LongArray[word]
        #print(word)
        if localString[:2] == ShortArray[word]:
            print(LongArray[word])
            print(word)
```

Here is the full code:

```py
kleuren = ["Rood","Geel","Groen","Blauw","Wit","Paars","Oranje","Zwart"]
KleurenShort = []

def splitArray(string):
    for lenght in range(int(len(string) / 2)):
        KleurenShort.append(string[:2])
        print(KleurenShort)
        string = string.strip(string[:2])
    return KleurenShort

def tekst_naar_kleur(string):
    return 0


def matchFirst2Letters(ShortArray,LongArray):
    for word in range(int(len(ShortArray))):
        localString = LongArray[word]
        #print(word)
        if localString[:2] == ShortArray[word]:
            print(LongArray[word])
            print(word)

matchFirst2Letters(splitArray("RoGeGrBl"),kleuren)
```

The outcome is:

```
['Ro']
['Ro', 'Ge']
['Ro', 'Ge', 'rB']
['Ro', 'Ge', 'rB', 'l']
```

when it should be:

```
['Ro']
['Ro', 'Ge']
['Ro', 'Ge', 'Gr']
['Ro', 'Ge', 'Gr', 'Bl']
```

Comment: Could you explain, what the code is supposed to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the use of the `string.strip()` method.

```
'aaaaaabcdb'.strip('ab')
```

gives `'cd'` as every instance of 'a' and 'b' in your input string is removed. You can simply get rid of the first two letters of the input string by indexing:

`'abcde'[2:]` will give `'cde'`.

Implemented in your code the corrected version is:

```
kleuren = ["Rood","Geel","Groen","Blauw","Wit","Paars","Oranje","Zwart"]
KleurenShort = []

def splitArray(string):
    for lenght in range(int(len(string) / 2)):
        KleurenShort.append(string[:2])
        print(KleurenShort)
        string = string[2:]
    return KleurenShort

def tekst_naar_kleur(string):
    return 0


def matchFirst2Letters(ShortArray,LongArray):
    for word in range(int(len(ShortArray))):
        localString = LongArray[word]
        #print(word)
        if localString[:2] == ShortArray[word]:
            print(LongArray[word])
            print(word)

matchFirst2Letters(splitArray("RoGeGrBl"),kleuren)
```

which outputs

```
['Ro']
['Ro', 'Ge']
['Ro', 'Ge', 'Gr']
['Ro', 'Ge', 'Gr', 'Bl']
Rood
0
Geel
1
Groen
2
Blauw
3
```

With the answer from the comment linked below, your `splitArray` function simply becomes:

```
def splitArray(string):
    return [string[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(string), 2)]
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character for a easier and faster version of how to split a string into pairs of 2.