# Split a string into groups of letters, ignoring whitespace

Tags: python, string, split

I am trying to split a string into groups of 4 letters.
Not into a list in a string.
without using import

Example 1:

```
hello world
```

Output:

```
hell owor ld
```

Example 2:

```
if you can dream it, you can do it
```

Output:

```
ifyo ucan drea mit, youc ando it
```

Comment: You'll find different ways to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to strip all whitespace from the input, then use `re.findall` on the pattern `.{1,4}` to find all blocks of 4 (or however many available) characters.  Then join that list together by space to generate the final output.

```py
inp = "if you can dream it, you can do it"
parts = re.findall(r'.{1,4}', re.sub(r'\s+', '', inp))
output = ' '.join(parts)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
ifyo ucan drea mit, youc ando it
```

Comment: Any idea without using import ?

Comment: @rolaMulla Use `import re`

Answer (score 1):

```
full_word = "hello world, how are you?"
full_word = full_word.replace(" ", "")
output = ""
for i in range(0, len(a)-8, 4):
    output += full_word[i:i + 4]
    output += " "
print(output)
```

output = hell owor ld,h owar eyou ?

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution without the need of importing re:

```
input_string = "if you can dream it, you can do it"

# The number of characters wanted
chunksize=4

# Without importing re

# Remove spaces
input_string_without_spaces = "".join(input_string.split())

# Result as a list
result_as_list = [input_string_without_spaces[i:i+chunksize] for i in range(0, len(input_string_without_spaces), chunksize)]

# Result as string
result_as_string = " ".join(result_as_list)

print(result_as_string)
```

Output:

```
ifyo ucan drea mit, youc ando it
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find my solution below with explanation

```
string  = "if you can dream it, you can do it"

string = string.replace(' ','') #replace whitespace so all words in string join each other

n = 4 # give space after every n chars
  

out = [(string[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(string), n)] # Using list comprehension to adjust each words with 4 characters in a list
  
# Printing output and converting list back to string 
print(' '.join(out))
```

output :

```
ifyo ucan drea mit, youc ando it
```

Answer (score -1):

```
pattern = "if you can dream it, you can do it"

i = 0
result = ""
for s in pattern:
    if not s == " ":
        if i == 4:
            i = 0
            result += " "
        result += s
        i += 1
print(result)
```

output:

```
ifyo ucan drea mit, youc ando it
```