# Split the column of dataframe into multiple columns according to the text length of column on Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I separate a column of pandas dataframe into multiple columns based on the size of each text length? Assume that chunk size will be 3 and the sample dataframe is:

```
id body
1 abcdefgh
2 xyzk
```

For this case, I would like to get:

```
id body1 body2 body3
1  abc  def gh
2  xyz  k
```

I am assuming that I should be able to handle it with something like : `df[['body1','body2', 'body3']] = df['body'].str.split(...`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
new_values = df['body'].str.findall('.{1,3}')
new_columns = [f'body{num}' for num in range(1, new_values.apply(len).max() +1)]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=new_values.tolist(), columns=new_columns)
```

You can also define your regex pattern based on the maximum number of characters you want on each column:

```
max_char_per_column = 3
regex_pattern = f".{{1,{max_char_per_column}}}"
new_values = df['body'].str.findall(regex_pattern)
```

If you don't want the None, feel free to `.fillna("")` your `new_df`.

See this answer for splitting a string with regex every nth character [Split string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character).

Answer (score 0):

First, define a `split_chunk` function

```
def split_chunk(txt, n=3):
    return [txt[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(txt), n)]
```

Then create a new dataframe from `body` using `apply`

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.body.apply(split_chunk).to_list())
>>> df2
     0    1     2
0  abc  def    gh
1  xyz    k  None
```

You can replace the None values, and rename the columns with the following

```
>>> df2 = df2.fillna("").rename(columns=lambda x: f"body{x+1}")
>>> df2
  body1 body2 body3
0   abc   def    gh
1   xyz     k
```

Finaly, restore the index

```
>>> df2.index = df.id
>>> df2
   body1 body2 body3
id
1    abc   def    gh
2    xyz     k
```

**Shorter version**

```
df = df.set_index("id")

df = pd.DataFrame(
         df.body.apply(split_chunk).to_list(), 
         index=df.index
     ).fillna("").rename(columns=lambda x: f"body{x+1}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"body": ["abcdefgh","xyzk"]})
df['body1'] = df['body'].astype(str).str[0:3]
df['body2'] = df['body'].astype(str).str[3:6]
df['body3'] = df['body'].astype(str).str[6:9]
df.drop('body',axis=1,inplace=True)
print(df)
```