# split-string-every-nth-character with nth+1 separator '0'

Tags: python, character, separator

I have a serie of digits that are string, for example :
IN : '01110100001101001001110100'

I want to split as follow:
OUT: ['01110100', '0', '01101001', '0','01110100]

We can notice that ninth '0' is a separator of list of digits that are binary.

Said otherwise : first eighth, sperator'0',next height, separator '0', next height, separator '0', etc

I know how to split using nth element ([Split string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character)), but the issue here is a bit more complicated:there is a separator '0'

Thanks a lot for your help.

Kindest regards

Comment: You can easily do this with `re.findall()`. Use a regexp with two capture groups: the first one matches 8 digits, the second one matches the `0` separator.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help.  Could you show how exactly to do this.  A concrete illustration would help, as it is normally the convention in stack overflow.   Thanks in advance and kindest regards

Comment: you can use loop to get `[:8]` and replace `IN = IN[8:]`, next get `[:1]` and replace `IN = IN[1:]`, (end of loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with capture groups.

```
import re

instr = '01110100001101001001110100'
outlist = list(sum(re.findall(r'(\d{8})(\d)', instr), ()))

print(outlist)
```

`re.findall()` returns a list of tuples, `list(sum(..., ())` flattens it into a single list.

Comment: Thanks a lot and kindest regards

Answer (score 1):

You just want to alternate between grabbing a slice of length 8, and then a slice of length 1, right?

```
def get_slices(string):
    from itertools import islice, cycle

    string_iter = iter(string)
    slice_lens = cycle([8, 1])

    while slc := "".join(islice(string_iter, next(slice_lens))):
        yield slc

print(list(get_slices("abcdefghijklmnopqr")))
```

Output:

```
['abcdefgh', 'i', 'jklmnopq', 'r']
```

Comment: It works perfectly ! Thanks a lot and kindest regards

Comment: @LaurentSalé Glad it's working! I've edited my answer with a slightly more compact version (requires Python 3.8.)