# Splitting a string every 2 digits

Tags: python, string, split, digits

I have a column existing of rows with different strings (Python). ex.

1. 5456656352
2. 435365
3. 46765432
   ...

I want to seperate the strings every 2 digits with a comma, so I have following result:

1. 54,56,65,63,52
2. 43,53,65
3. 46,76,54,32
   ...

Can someone help me please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the structure of desired output (pandas and dataframes, pure strings, etc.). But, you can always use a regex pattern like:

```py
import re
re.findall("\d{2}", "5456656352")
```

##### Output

```
['54', '56', '65', '63', '52']
```

You can have this output as a string too:

```py
",".join(re.findall("\d{2}", "5456656352"))
```

##### Output

```
54,56,65,63,52
```

##### Explanation

`\d{2}` is a regex pattern that points to a part of a string that has 2 digits. Using `findall` function, this pattern will divide each string to elements containing just two digits.

##### Edit

Based on your comment, you want to **APPLY** this on a column. In this case, you should do something like:

```py
df["my_column"] = df["my_column"].apply(split_it)
```

Comment: I need to apply this function to one column of a dataframe. This is what I tried but I get an error message ('Series' object has no attribute 'split_it'). Probably somehing goes wrong with the selection of the rows of my columns.import re
def split_it(Age):
    ",".join(re.findall("\d{2}", Age))
    
df['DMAge']= df['DMAge'].split_it(df[:,'DMAge'])

Comment: @WoutervanEpperzeel Thanks for the comment. I have edited the answer as per your comment.

Comment: How should I build my funtion? The input of my function is every row of the column I guess? Because find all only works for a string (=row of columns) and not a whole colomn. I have now this as function: def split_it(Age):
    ",".join(re.findall("\d{2}", Age)) where age represent a row of a column

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
text = "5456656352"
print(",".join(text[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(text), 2)))
```

output:

```
54,56,65,63,52
```

You can wrap it into a function if you want to apply it to a DF or ...

**note**: This will separate from left, so if the length is odd, there will be a single number at the end.

Comment: Hi SorousH, can you explain how I need to build my function. I am a bit confused whit the input parameters of the function. I think it need to be a row of a column of my df, but not sure about it

Comment: @WoutervanEpperzeel You can pass this lambda to `.apply()` method of your DataFrame : `lambda text: ",".join(text[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(text), 2))`